# What is the boundary in multipart/form-data?

Tags: html, http, forms

I want to ask a question about the `multipart/form-data`. In the HTTP header, I find that the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=???`.

Is the `???` free to be defined by the user? Or is it generated from the HTML? Is it possible for me to define the `??? = abcdefg`?

Comment: I found this is the answer.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Comment: Related Q&A: [What if the form-data boundary is contained in the attached file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29539498/2718186)

Comment: Does the boundary get uploaded to the server along with whatever data was posted, so the server automatically uses boundary string specified instead of the default "&" to separate the different values submitted?

Answer (score 578):

> Is the `???` free to be defined by the user?

Yes.

> or is it supplied by the HTML?

No. [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) has ***nothing*** to do with that. Read below.

> Is it possible for me to define the `???` as `abcdefg`?

Yes.

If you want to send the following data to the web server:

```
name = John
age = 12
```

using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` would be like this:

```
name=John&age=12
```

As you can see, the server knows that parameters are separated by an ampersand `&`. If `&` is required for a parameter value then it must be encoded.

So how does the server know where a parameter value starts and ends when it receives an HTTP request using `multipart/form-data`?

Using the *boundary*, similar to `&`.

For example:

```
--XXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

John
--XXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="age"

12
--XXX--
```

In that case, the boundary value is `XXX`. You specify it in the `Content-Type` header so that the server knows ***how to split*** the data it receives.

So you need to:

- Use a value that won't appear in the HTTP data sent to the server.
- Be consistent and use the same value everywhere in the request message.

Comment: Yout have to add an extra "--" in the end of boundary.

Comment: You can read it in documentation. Boundary ending have to have extra two hypens "--"

Link: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Comment: Great answer. A boundary is just the 'key' to separate the multiple "parts" of a multipart payload. Normally something like '&' is enough to separate the variables but you need something more unique to separate the payloads within the payload.

Comment: Note: Content-Length should be changed whene the boundary change

Comment: @K3rnel31 Of course, unless the new boundary string has the same length.

Comment: I think that the boundary value as declared in the Content-Type header will actually be -XXX--- because an extra "--" should be written when separating the parts (hence the ---XXX---)

Comment: Would be clearer if you didn't include any dashes in the boundary, since that would clearly show which dashes are included because of the protocol.

Comment: Note, however, that if you're using the FormData object from JavaScript, it will set its own boundary irrespective of the value in the Content-Type header.

Comment: @e18r What should we do with it though? I'm facing the error too but couldn't get over it

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh I don't remember what I did. That comment is 5 years old lol sorry

Comment: @e18r My answer was "don't set the header yourself"

Answer (score 169):

The answer to substance of the question is **yes**. **You can use an arbitrary value for the `boundary` parameter** as long as it is less than 70 bytes long and only contains [7-bit `US-ASCII`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US-ASCII) (printable) characters.

If you use one of `multipart/*` content types, you are actually *required* to specify the `boundary` parameter in the `Content-Type` header. Otherwise, in the case of an HTTP request, the server will be unable to parse the payload.

Unless you are absolutely certain that only the `US-ASCII` character set will be used in its payload, you may want to add a `Content-Type` header to each part, with the `charset` parameter set to `UTF-8`.

A few relevant excerpts from the [RFC2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt):

- 4.1. Text Media Type

  > A "charset" parameter may be used to indicate the character set of the body text for "text" subtypes, notably including the subtype "text/plain", which is a generic subtype for plain text.
- 4.1.2. Charset Parameter

  > A critical parameter that may be specified in the Content-Type field
  > for "text/plain" data is the character set.

  > Unlike some other parameter values, the values of the charset parameter are NOT case sensitive.  The default character set, which must be assumed in the absence of a charset parameter, is US-ASCII.
- 5.1.  Multipart Media Type

  > As stated in the definition of the Content-Transfer-Encoding field [RFC 2045], no encoding other than "7bit", "8bit", or "binary" is permitted for entities of type "multipart".  The "multipart" boundary delimiters and header fields are always represented as 7bit US-ASCII in any case (though the header fields may encode non-US-ASCII header text as per RFC 2047) and data within the body parts can be encoded on a part-by-part basis, with Content-Transfer-Encoding fields for each appropriate body part.

  > The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter, "boundary". The boundary delimiter line is then defined as a line consisting entirely of two hyphen characters ("-", decimal value 45) followed by the boundary parameter value from the Content-Type header field, optional linear whitespace, and a terminating CRLF.

  > Boundary delimiters must not appear within the encapsulated material, and must be no longer than 70 characters, not counting the two leading hyphens.

  > The boundary delimiter line following the last body part is a distinguished delimiter that indicates that no further body parts will follow.  Such a delimiter line is identical to the previous delimiter lines, with the addition of two more hyphens after the boundary parameter value.

Here is an example using an arbitrary boundary:

```http
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="yet another boundary"

--yet another boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"

bar
--yet another boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="baz"

quux
--yet another boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="feels"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8


--yet another boundary--
```

Comment: I like this answer most because it quotes from RFC about how **hyphens** are specified.

Comment: @Rick There's a valid reason for IETF to do that — although they all look pretty much the same, only one of the following four is the correct hyphen character: ˗ ‐ - ‑

Comment: ha, when I said hypens, I mean your answer told me which hypens are defined in the standard. I was confused about which hypens are "client defined" and which are "specification defined"

Answer (score 70):

multipart/form-data contains *boundary* to separate name/value pairs. The boundary acts like a marker of each chunk of name/value pairs passed when a form gets submitted. The boundary is automatically added to a content-type of a request header.

The form with **enctype="multipart/form-data"** attribute will have a request header Content-Type :  multipart/form-data; boundary  --- WebKit193844043-h (*browser generated vaue*).

The payload passed looks something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

    -----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”file”; filename=”captcha”
    Content-Type:

    -----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”action”

    submit
    -----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

On the webservice side, it's consumed in @Consumes("multipart/form-data") form.

Beware, when testing your webservice using chrome postman, you need to check the form data option(radio button) and File menu from the dropdown box to send attachment. Explicit provision of content-type as multipart/form-data throws an error. Because boundary is missing as it overrides the curl request of post man to server with content-type by appending the boundary which works fine.

See [RFC1341 sec7.2 The Multipart Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

Comment: Is the value of the boundary generated on the fly for every request, or is it possible to determine it ahead of time?

Comment: Normally you can. But if you use a tool such as `postman`, there is no way you can specify the boundary, `postman` will always generate it for you. You can use `fiddler` to check it out.

Answer (score -6):

use this

```
headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
```

for boundary error

Answer (score -7):

we have to split our data. So, the server understands what we send.

1 Example: We split data

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$p_id = $_POST['pid'];
```

2.Example: if We send JSON data ( With ) content type Multipart/form-data, we get a warning related to boundary

```
 $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: Suppose I am converting a json object to form data and passing the values to php with `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` , so in this case what I have to do ?  Adding `$json = file_get_contents("php://input");` will work ? Right now I am getting success but getting empty row fields in db.

Comment: just take json obj and decode using json_decode than take single value and store in variable.       

my json :

{
    "username":"xyz",
    "email":"xyz@gmail.com",
}

my php 
    $json = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $email = json_decode($json)->email;

    echo $email;
@NoobCoder

Comment: I am splitting data just like you posted  -> ` $id = isset($_POST['field1']) ? $_POST['field1'] : '';
    $id1 = isset($_POST['field2']) ? $_POST['field2'] : '';` and passing these `$id` to query. What if I make changes on POST call in js. Content-type I am using is `mulipart/form-data`

Comment: try application/json as content type  @NoobCoder