# How to send a "multipart/form-data" with requests in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

How to send a `multipart/form-data` with `requests` in python? How to send a file, I understand, but how to send the form data by this method can not understand.

Comment: your question is not really clear. What do you want to achieve? Do you wish to send "multipart/form-data" without a file upload in the form?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64586578/8826047 The boundary is important!

Answer (score 361):

Basically, if you specify a `files` parameter (a dictionary), then `requests` will send a `multipart/form-data` POST instead of a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST. You are not limited to using actual files in that dictionary, however:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', files=dict(foo='bar'))
>>> response.status_code
200
```

and httpbin.org lets you know what headers you posted with; in `response.json()` we have:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(response.json()['headers'])
{'Accept': '*/*',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'Connection': 'close',
 'Content-Length': '141',
 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; '
                 'boundary=c7cbfdd911b4e720f1dd8f479c50bc7f',
 'Host': 'httpbin.org',
 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.21.0'}
```

And just to be explicit: you should **not** set the `Content-Type` header when you use the `files` parameter, leave this to `requests` because it needs to specify a (unique) boundary value in the header that matches the value used in the request body.

Better still, you can further control the filename, content type and additional headers for each part by using a tuple instead of a single string or bytes object. The tuple is expected to contain between 2 and 4 elements; the filename, the content, optionally a content type, and an optional dictionary of further headers.

I'd use the tuple form with `None` as the filename, so that the `filename="..."` parameter is dropped from the request for those parts:

```
>>> files = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> print(requests.Request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', files=files).prepare().body.decode('utf8'))
--bb3f05a247b43eede27a124ef8b968c5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"; filename="foo"

bar
--bb3f05a247b43eede27a124ef8b968c5--
>>> files = {'foo': (None, 'bar')}
>>> print(requests.Request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', files=files).prepare().body.decode('utf8'))
--d5ca8c90a869c5ae31f70fa3ddb23c76
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"

bar
--d5ca8c90a869c5ae31f70fa3ddb23c76--
```

`files` can also be a list of two-value tuples, if you need ordering and/or multiple fields with the same name:

```
requests.post(
    'http://requestb.in/xucj9exu',
    files=(
        ('foo', (None, 'bar')),
        ('foo', (None, 'baz')),
        ('spam', (None, 'eggs')),
    )
)
```

If you specify both `files` and `data`, then it depends on the *value* of `data` what will be used to create the POST body. If `data` is a string, only it willl be used; otherwise both `data` and `files` are used, with the elements in `data` listed first.

There is also the excellent `requests-toolbelt` project, which includes [advanced Multipart support](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html). It takes field definitions in the same format as the `files` parameter, but unlike `requests`, it defaults to not setting a filename parameter. In addition, it can stream the request from open file objects, where `requests` will first construct the request body in memory:

```
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

mp_encoder = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
        'foo': 'bar',
        # plain file object, no filename or mime type produces a
        # Content-Disposition header with just the part name
        'spam': ('spam.txt', open('spam.txt', 'rb'), 'text/plain'),
    }
)
r = requests.post(
    'http://httpbin.org/post',
    data=mp_encoder,  # The MultipartEncoder is posted as data, don't use files=...!
    # The MultipartEncoder provides the content-type header with the boundary:
    headers={'Content-Type': mp_encoder.content_type}
)
```

Fields follow the same conventions; use a tuple with between 2 and 4 elements to add a filename, part mime-type or extra headers. Unlike the `files` parameter, no attempt is made to find a default `filename` value if you don't use a tuple.

Answer (score 143):

Requests has changed since some of the previous answers were written. Have a look at [this Issue on Github](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1081) for more details and [this comment](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1081#issuecomment-32956681) for an example.

In short, the `files` parameter takes a dictionary with the key being the name of the form field and the value being either a string or a 2, 3 or 4-length tuple, as described in the section [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) in the Requests quickstart:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
```

In the above, the tuple is composed as follows:

```
(filename, data, content_type, headers)
```

If the value is just a string, the filename will be the same as the key, as in the following:

```
>>> files = {'obvius_session_id': '72c2b6f406cdabd578c5fd7598557c52'}

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="obvius_session_id"; filename="obvius_session_id"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

72c2b6f406cdabd578c5fd7598557c52
```

If the value is a tuple and the first entry is `None` the filename property will not be included:

```
>>> files = {'obvius_session_id': (None, '72c2b6f406cdabd578c5fd7598557c52')}

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="obvius_session_id"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

72c2b6f406cdabd578c5fd7598557c52
```

Comment: What if you need to distinguish the `name` and `filename` but also have multiple fields with the same name?

Comment: I have a simillar problem as @Michael . Can you have a look at the question and suggest something?  [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683352/how-to-upload-multipart-encode-file-and-form-data-as-a-payload)

Comment: did someone solve this problem with having multiple fields with the same name?

Comment: files={"type1":("","value1"), "type2":("","value2")}

Comment: The trick to pass en empty string as the first value of a `files` tuple does not work anymore: you need to use `requests.post` `data` parameter instead to send additionnal non-file `multipart/form-data` parameters

Comment: Passing `None` instead of an empty string seems to work

Comment: Using '' in the first value still sends the filename='' in the request. `None` really works.

Comment: Using '' in the first value still sends the filename='' in the request. `None` really works.

Answer (score 137):

You need to use the `files` parameter to send a multipart form POST request *even* when you do not need to upload any files.

From the original [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L16) source:

```python
def request(method, url, **kwargs):
    """Constructs and sends a :class:`Request <Request>`.

    ...
    :param files: (optional) Dictionary of ``'name': file-like-objects``
        (or ``{'name': file-tuple}``) for multipart encoding upload.
        ``file-tuple`` can be a 2-tuple ``('filename', fileobj)``,
        3-tuple ``('filename', fileobj, 'content_type')``
        or a 4-tuple ``('filename', fileobj, 'content_type', custom_headers)``,
        where ``'content-type'`` is a string
        defining the content type of the given file
        and ``custom_headers`` a dict-like object 
        containing additional headers to add for the file.
```

The relevant part is: **`file-tuple`** `can be a`:

- **`2-tuple`** (*filename, fileobj*)
- **`3-tuple`** (*filename, fileobj, content_type*)
- **`4-tuple`** (*filename, fileobj, content_type, custom_headers*).

> <sup>☝  What might not be obvious is that **`fileobj`** can be *either* an actual file object when dealing with files, *OR* a string when dealing with plain text fields.</sup>

Based on the above, the simplest multipart form request that includes both files to upload and form fields will look like this:

```python
import requests

multipart_form_data = {
    'upload': ('custom_file_name.zip', open('myfile.zip', 'rb')),
    'action': (None, 'store'),
    'path': (None, '/path1')
}

response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', files=multipart_form_data)

print(response.content)
```

☝ *Note the `None` as the first argument in the tuple for plain text fields — this is a placeholder for the filename field which is only used for file uploads, but for text fields passing `None` as the first parameter is required in order for the data to be submitted.*

#### Multiple fields with the same name

If you need to post multiple fields with the same name then instead of a dictionary you can define your payload as a list (or a tuple) of tuples:

```
multipart_form_data = (
    ('file2', ('custom_file_name.zip', open('myfile.zip', 'rb'))),
    ('action', (None, 'store')),
    ('path', (None, '/path1')),
    ('path', (None, '/path2')),
    ('path', (None, '/path3')),
)
```

---

#### Streaming requests API

If the above API is not pythonic enough for you, then consider using [requests toolbelt](http://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/uploading-data.html#streaming-multipart-data-encoder) (`pip install requests_toolbelt`) which is an extension of the [core requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module that provides support for file upload streaming as well as the [MultipartEncoder](http://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html#multipart-form-data-encoder) which can be used instead of `files`, and which also lets you define the payload as a dictionary, tuple or list.

`MultipartEncoder` can be used both for multipart requests with or without actual upload fields. It must be assigned to the `data` parameter.

```python
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
            # a file upload field
            'file': ('file.zip', open('file.zip', 'rb'), 'text/plain')
            # plain text fields
            'field0': 'value0', 
            'field1': 'value1',
           }
    )

response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=multipart_data,
                  headers={'Content-Type': multipart_data.content_type})
```

If you need to send multiple fields with the same name, or if the order of form fields is important, then a tuple or a list can be used instead of a dictionary:

```
multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
    fields=(
            ('action', 'ingest'), 
            ('item', 'spam'),
            ('item', 'sausage'),
            ('item', 'eggs'),
           )
    )
```

Comment: Amazing.  Inexplicably, an api I am working with requires 2 different values for the same key.  This is amazing.  Thank you.

Comment: @ccpizza, what actually this line means? > "('file.py', open('file.py', 'rb'), 'text/plain')".
It doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @DenisKoreyba: this is an example of a file upload field which assumes that the a file named `file.py` is located in the same folder as your script.

Comment: You can use `None` instead of empty string. Then requests will not include a filename at all. So instead of `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"; filename=""` it will be `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"`. This was critical for me for the server to accept those fields as form fields and not as files.

Comment: I was looking for something simliar to what javascript has https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData to send multiple fields with the same name. Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. You are a hero!

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how to highlight this answer for other people to reference. I spent whole day but this answer finally solved my issue.

Comment: This is the answer that solved the issue for me. As an additional note, my specific use case required an empty "file" field, so this worked for me: `form_data = {"file": ("", None, "application/octet-stream")}`

Comment: re:multiple fields with same name- I had to make it a list of tuples, not a tuple of tuples,  to work.

Answer (score 31):

Here is the simple code snippet to upload a single file with additional parameters using requests:

```
url = 'https://<file_upload_url>'
fp = '/Users/jainik/Desktop/data.csv'

files = {'file': open(fp, 'rb')}
payload = {'file_id': '1234'}

response = requests.put(url, files=files, data=payload, verify=False)
```

Please note that you don't need to explicitly specify any content type.

NOTE: Wanted to comment on one of the above answers but could not because of low reputation so drafted a new response here.

Comment: The least verbose and easiest to understand. Anyway, should a file be `open`ed with`'rb'` option?

Comment: Yes this hits the core of it: `files` and `data` both as dicts

Comment: After many long and complicated answers above, this one goes directly to the core and works!

Comment: What is the reason for verify=False? It seems to me that disabling the ssl cert check is unnecessary and potentially dangerous

Answer (score 12):

By specifying a `files` parameter in the `POST` request, the `Content-Type` of the request is **automatically** set to `multipart/form-data` (followed by the [`boundary`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data) string used to separate each body part in the multipart payload), whether you send only `files`, or `form-data` and `files` at the same time (thus, one **shouldn't attempt setting the** `Content-Type` **manually** in this case). Whereas, if only `form-data` were sent, the `Content-Type` would automatically be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You can print out the `Content-Type` header of the request to verify the above using the example given below, which shows how to upload multiple files (or a single file) with (optionally) the same `key` (i.e., `'files'` in the case below), as well as with optional `form-data` (i.e., `data=data` in the example below). The documentation on how to `POST` single and multiple `files` can be found [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) and [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files), respectively. In case you need to upload large files without reading them into memory, have a look at [Streaming Uploads](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads).
For the server side—in case this is needed—please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), from which the code snippet below has been taken, and which uses the [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) web framework.

### Example

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit'
files = [('files', open('a.txt', 'rb')), ('files', open('b.txt', 'rb'))]
#file = {'file': open('a.txt','rb')} # to send a single file
data ={"name": "foo", "point": 0.13, "is_accepted": False}
r = requests.post(url=url, data=data, files=files) 
print(r.json())
print(r.request.headers['content-type'])
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the `name` attribute of the upload file that is in the HTML of the site. Example:

```
autocomplete="off" name="image">
```

You see  `name="image">`? You can find it in the HTML of a site for uploading the file. You need to use it to upload the file with `Multipart/form-data`

script:

```
import requests

site = 'https://prnt.sc/upload.php' # the site where you upload the file
filename = 'image.jpg'  # name example
```

Here, in the place of image, add the name of the upload file in HTML

```
up = {'image':(filename, open(filename, 'rb'), "multipart/form-data")}
```

If the upload requires to click the button for upload, you can use like that:

```
data = {
     "Button" : "Submit",
}
```

Then start the request

```
request = requests.post(site, files=up, data=data)
```

And done, file uploaded succesfully

Answer (score 5):

```
import requests
# assume sending two files
url = "put ur url here"
f1 = open("file 1 path", 'rb')
f2 = open("file 2 path", 'rb')
response = requests.post(url,files={"file1 name": f1, "file2 name":f2})
print(response)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import json
import os
import requests
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

AUTH_API_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:3095/api/auth/login"

def file_upload(path_img, token ):
    url = 'http://localhost:3095/api/shopping/product/image'
    name_img = os.path.basename(path_img)

    mp_encoder = MultipartEncoder(
        fields={
            'email': 'mcm9@gmail.com',
            'source': 'tmall',
            'productId': 'product_0001',
            'image': (name_img, open(path_img, 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')
        #'spam': ('spam.txt', open('spam.txt', 'rb'), 'text/plain'),
        }
    )

    head = {'Authorization': 'Bearer  {}'.format(token),
            'Content-Type': mp_encoder.content_type}

    with requests.Session() as s:
        result = s.post(url, data=mp_encoder, headers=head)

    return result

def do_auth(username, password, url=AUTH_API_ENDPOINT):
    data = {
        "email": username,
        "password": password
    }

    # sending post request and saving response as response object
    r = requests.post(url=url, data=data)

    # extracting response text
    response_text = r.text

    d = json.loads(response_text)
    # print(d)

    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = do_auth('mcm4@gmail.com','123456')
    token = result.get('data').get('payload').get('token')
    print(token)
    result = file_upload('/home/mcm/Pictures/1234.png',token)
    print(result.json())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

## Send multipart/form-data key and value

curl command:

```sh
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/xxx ...
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----xxx' \
-F taskStatus=1
```

python [requests - More complicated POST requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

```py
    updateTaskUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/xxx"
    updateInfoDict = {
        "taskStatus": 1,
    }
    resp = requests.put(updateTaskUrl, data=updateInfoDict)
```

## Send multipart/form-data file

curl command:

```sh
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/xxx ...
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----xxx' \
-F file=@/Users/xxx.txt
```

python [requests - POST a Multipart-Encoded File](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

```py
    filePath = "/Users/xxx.txt"
    fileFp = open(filePath, 'rb')
    fileInfoDict = {
        "file": fileFp,
    }
    resp = requests.post(uploadResultUrl, files=fileInfoDict)
```

that's all.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify examples given above,

"You need to use the files parameter to send a multipart form POST request even when you do not need to upload any files."

files={}

won't work, unfortunately.

You will need to put some dummy values in, e.g.

```
files={"foo": "bar"}
```

I came up against this when trying to upload files to Bitbucket's REST API and had to write this abomination to avoid the dreaded "Unsupported Media Type" error:

```
url = "https://my-bitbucket.com/rest/api/latest/projects/FOO/repos/bar/browse/foobar.txt"
payload = {'branch': 'master', 
           'content': 'text that will appear in my file',
           'message': 'uploading directly from python'}
files = {"foo": "bar"}
response = requests.put(url, data=payload, files=files)
```

:O=

Comment: Couldn't you do `requests.put(url, files=payload)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python snippet you need to upload one large single file as multipart formdata. With NodeJs Multer middleware running on the server side.

```
import requests
latest_file = 'path/to/file'
url = "http://httpbin.org/apiToUpload"
files = {'fieldName': open(latest_file, 'rb')}
r = requests.put(url, files=files)
```

For the server side please check the multer documentation at: https://github.com/expressjs/multer
here the field single('fieldName') is used to accept one single file, as in:

```
var upload = multer().single('fieldName');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to send file in multipart request

```
import requests
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer <token>"}
myfile = 'file.txt'
myfile2 = {'file': (myfile, open(myfile, 'rb'),'application/octet-stream')}
url = 'https://example.com/path'
r = requests.post(url, files=myfile2, headers=headers,verify=False)
print(r.content)
```

Other approach

```
import requests

url = "https://example.com/path"

payload={}
files=[
  ('file',('file',open('/path/to/file','rb'),'application/octet-stream'))
]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

I have tested both , both works fine.

Comment: What is the difference between "data" and "files"?

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to send a request to URL_server with request module in python 3.
This works for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 *-*
import json, requests

URL_SERVER_TO_POST_DATA = "URL_to_send_POST_request"
HEADERS = {"Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data;"}

def getPointsCC_Function():
  file_data = {
      'var1': (None, "valueOfYourVariable_1"),
      'var2': (None, "valueOfYourVariable_2")
  }

  try:
    resElastic = requests.post(URL_GET_BALANCE, files=file_data)
    res = resElastic.json()
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)

  print (json.dumps(res, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

getPointsCC_Function()
```

Where:

- URL_SERVER_TO_POST_DATA = Server where we going to send data
- HEADERS = Headers sended
- file_data = Params sended

Answer (score -2):

Postman generated code for file upload with additional form fields:

```
import http.client
import mimetypes
from codecs import encode

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("data.XXXX.com")
dataList = []
boundary = 'wL36Yn8afVp8Ag7AmP8qZ0SA4n1v9T'
dataList.append(encode('--' + boundary))
dataList.append(encode('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=batchSize;'))

dataList.append(encode('Content-Type: {}'.format('text/plain')))
dataList.append(encode(''))

dataList.append(encode("1"))
dataList.append(encode('--' + boundary))
dataList.append(encode('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename={0}'.format('FileName-1.json')))

fileType = mimetypes.guess_type('FileName-1.json')[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
dataList.append(encode('Content-Type: {}'.format(fileType)))
dataList.append(encode(''))

with open('FileName-1.json', 'rb') as f:
  dataList.append(f.read())
dataList.append(encode('--'+boundary+'--'))
dataList.append(encode(''))
body = b'\r\n'.join(dataList)
payload = body
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary={}'.format(boundary)
}
conn.request("POST", "/fileupload/uri/XXXX", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: The answer above is a little unclear but what it did assist me in understanding, is to use the `encode()` function.