# Post to API works on Postman but the generated Python code does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests, postman

The following code was generated by Postman on a successful post. However, when i tried to run it on Python i got Response [409], which said only PDF or JPEG files are accepted, even though the file I submited is a PDF. Hope someone can help me out on this one. Already searched for a few days, but couldn't get it working. I can't take the headers off, because the website requires authentification. I was successfull getting the token and session.

```
payload = {'integracaoDocumento.nomeVitima': 'Outroteste da Costa',
           'integracaoDocumento.rgVitima': '1234',
           'integracaoDocumento.uploadDocumentoList[0].descricao': 'BO 1234',
           'integracaoDocumento.uploadDocumentoList[0].idTipoDocumento': '1',
           'integracaoDocumento.uploadDocumentoList[0].identificador': 'BO 1234',
           'dadosRegistro.dataRegistroDelegacia': '11/09/2016',
           'dadosRegistro.idDelegaciaRegistro': '141',
           'dadosRegistro.idDelegaciaApuracao': '227',
           'dadosFato.data': '10/12/2015',
           'dadosFato.periodo': 'T',
           'dadosFato.idMunicipio': '5508',
           'dadosFato.descricao': 'Descricao Fato Desaparecido',
           'dadosFato.idTipoLogradouro': '1',
           'dadosFato.logradouro': 'Rua de teste',
           'dadosFato.numero': '777',
           'dadosFato.complemento': 'Apt 123456',
           'dadosFato.cep': '21351110',
           'dadosFato.pontoReferencia': 'Perto do bar.',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.cnh': '123123123',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.nomeMae': 'Nome da Mae de Vitima Desaparecimento Instaurado 1',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.nomePai': 'Nome do Pai de Vitima Desaparecimento Instaurado 1',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.cpf': '94151587004',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.orgaoEmissorRg': 'DETRAN',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.tituloEleitor': '1234567890',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.ctps': '333222111',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.dataNascimento': '17/03/1959',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.idEstadoCivil': '1',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.passaporte': 'FT44225577',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.sexo': 'F',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.nacionalidade': 'B',
           'vitima.dadosBiograficos.idNaturalidade': '33',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.idAltura': '3',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.idTipoSanguineo': '2',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.idBiotipo': '1',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.idCorOlhos': '1',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.idCorPele': '2',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.idTipoCabelo': '1',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.idCorCabelo': '1',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.amputacoes[0]': '1',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.amputacoes[1]': '4',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.deformacoes[0]': '1',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.deficiencias[0]': '1',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.deficiencias[1]': '2',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.deficiencias[2]': '3',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.caracteristicasIndividualizantes[0].idCaracteristicaIndividualizante': '1',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.caracteristicasIndividualizantes[0].idParteCorpo': '2',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.caracteristicasIndividualizantes[0].descricao': 'Descricao caracteristica individualizante.',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.artigoPessoais[0].idArtigoPessoal': '1',
           'vitima.caracteristicasFisicas.artigoPessoais[0].idParteCorpo': '5',
           'vitima.enderecos[0].idUf': '53',
           'vitima.enderecos[0].idMunicipio': '5508',
           'vitima.enderecos[0].idTipoLogradouro': '3',
           'vitima.enderecos[0].logradouro': 'Rua de teste da Vitima Desaparecimento Instaurado 1',
           'vitima.enderecos[0].numero': '111',
           'vitima.enderecos[0].complemento': 'Casa 99',
           'vitima.enderecos[0].cep': '22735080',
           'vitima.enderecos[0].pontoReferencia': 'Perto da padaria.',
           'vitima.contatos[0].idTipoContato': '1',
           'vitima.contatos[0].descricaoContato': 'teste@teste.com.br',
           'vitima.contatos[1].idTipoContato': '2',
           'vitima.contatos[1].descricaoContato': 'Contato teste 1',
           'interessados[0].nome': 'Interessado teste 1',
           'interessados[0].cpf': '62784035018',
           'interessados[0].rg': '223566578',
           'interessados[0].orgaoEmissor': 'IFP',
           'interessados[0].nomePai': 'Pai interessado teste 1',
           'interessados[0].nomeMae': 'Mae Interessado teste 1',
           'interessados[0].idRelacaoVitima': '1',
           'interessados[0].meiosComunicacoes[0].idTipoMeioComunicao': '1',
           'interessados[0].meiosComunicacoes[0].descricao': 'Meio de comunicacao teste 1',
           'interessados[0].meiosComunicacoes[1].idTipoMeioComunicao': '2',
           'interessados[0].meiosComunicacoes[1].descricao': 'blah@blah.com.br',
           'interessados[1].nome': 'Interessado teste 2',
           'interessados[1].cpf': '14970635072',
           'interessados[1].rg': '1121346579',
           'interessados[1].orgaoEmissor': 'DETRAN',
           'interessados[1].nomePai': 'Pai interessado teste 1-1',
           'interessados[1].nomeMae': 'Mae Interessado teste 1-1',
           'interessados[1].idRelacaoVitima': '2',
           'interessados[1].meiosComunicacoes[0].idTipoMeioComunicao': '2',
           'interessados[1].meiosComunicacoes[0].descricao': 'AAAAA@FSDAFDSF.com.br'}
headers = {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
           'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=' + session,
           }
files = [('integracaoDocumento.uploadDocumentoList[0].arquivo',open(r'PATH_TO_FILE\FILE.pdf','rb'))]
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers = headers, data = payload, files = files, verify = False)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the prolem by getting the http.client code instead of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is re-written answer. I suggested to declare content-type, but according to [multipart data POST using python requests: no multipart boundary was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415084/multipart-data-post-using-python-requests-no-multipart-boundary-was-found) you shouldn't write it manually with Python requests.

Instead, there is `content-disposition` element which can be used to declare details of content. Perhaps just adding filename with right extension is enough for server to accept your file. Read further info from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: I tried to add the content-type and it returned Response 500 with an error message saying there was no multipart boundary. I'm not sure what the boundary should be, but i tried adding the one from the example on the API documentation (boundary=6o2knFse3p53ty9dmcQvWAIx1zInP11uCfbm). Then it returned Response 409 with an error message saying the request can't be empty. Any other ideas?