# Got text/plain for mimetype when upload image by requests/locust

Tags: python, express, python-requests, multer, locust

When I use dev tool like Postman to upload file, my [Express.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express) server using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

```
import multer from 'multer';

const upload = multer();
app.post('/api/upload-file',  upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

can parse the file correctly including `mimetype` field and prints

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'my.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  buffer: <Buffer ...>,
  size: 9693
}
```

However, when I use [locust](https://github.com/locustio/locust) (for load testing, and it is [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) backed) to upload same file by both of these two methods:

```
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

@task
def upload_img_1(self):
    file = open('path/to/my.png', 'rb')
    self.client.post(
        '/api/upload-file',
        files={'file': file})

@task
def upload_img_2(self):
    file = open('path/to/my.png', 'rb')
    m = MultipartEncoder(
        fields={'file': ('my.png', file, 'image/png')})
    self.client.post(
        '/api/upload-file',
        files={'file': m})
```

The `mimetype` I got in my Express.js server are `text/plain` which is wrong.

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'my.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/plain',
  buffer: <Buffer ...>,
  size: 9693
}
```

How to get correct `mimetype`?

Comment: hi! locust uses the requests package under the hood. maybe if you check its documentation, or google it in the context of requests rather than locust? or maybe all you need to do is add headers={"content-type": "image/png"} as a parameter to your .post call (not sure though)

Comment: @Cyberwiz thanks, I am aware of it. I actually made so far based on other `requests` demo. The right one I need for file uploading is `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`, however, [it is not supposed to set directly in the Python version header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415084/multipart-data-post-using-python-requests-no-multipart-boundary-was-found), otherwise I will get `Multipart: Boundary not found` error in my Express.js server side.

Comment: ok! Unfortunately I've never posted images myself so I dont know what to say :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally made it by

```
def upload_img(self):
    file = open('path/to/my.png', 'rb')
    files = {
        'file': ('my.png', file, 'image/png'),
    }
    self.client.post(
        '/api/upload-file',
        files=files)
```

This time the Express.js server can get `mimetype` file as `image/png` correctly.

Hope it will help people who might same issue in future.