# File uploading using Python requests.put function is rejected with Error 400

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a task to convert linux curl command into a Python function.
The commands itself is stright forward - it does upload a file onto a server:

```
curl -X PUT "http://xxx.yyy.zzz/planning/antennas/file" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@111.pafx"
```

The Python module I came up with as following:

```
  def PutAntennaFile(self,filename):
        files = {'file': open(filename, 'rb')}
        headers = {"Accept": "*/*",
                   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                   }
        r = requests.put(url=self.__url+'/planning/antennas/file', files=files, headers=headers,verify=False)
        print(r.text)
```

However, I'm constantly getting Error 400 'Bad Request' responce:

```
'b'{"error":"Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary.","type":"https://httpstatuses.com/400","title":"Plannig API error","status":400,"detail":"OK","instance":"/planning/antennas/file","extensions":{}}'`
```

and request itself is following:

```
b'--072fc9ea6990430c232050439f80f414\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="222.pafx"\r\n\r\nPK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00[7\xa9\xdd\x1e\x03\x00\x00\\\n\x00...'
```

Perhaps somebody can clarify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "but file field is there!" Try to explain specifically how your code causes "the `file` field to be there", and cross-reference with what the documentation (for Requests, and for the particular API you are using) says "the `file` field`" means.

Comment: you need to add a tuple in file field. try ```files = {'file': (filename,open(filename, 'rb'))}```

Comment: Yash, thank you for the comment. I've tried with the same error 400 responce.

Comment: I noticed that you've got an extra double quote in your header: `'multipart/form-data"'`. That might cause a 400, do you still get the same error without that?

Comment: Rob, I was too quick to reply. In fact removing extra quote does make difference. Error 400 gives another reason: b'{"error":"Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary.","type":"https://httpstatuses.com/400","title":"Plannig API error","status":400,"detail":"OK","instance":"/planning/antennas/file","extensions":{}}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After addressing Rob's comment regarding typo in the code the server came up with
different rejection cause.
The solution is described on the case below
[Error 400 related case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415084/multipart-data-post-using-python-requests-no-multipart-boundary-was-found)

In fact this case can be removed due to duplication.

Thanks a lot for your help and participation.