# unable to POST image through with files parameter python requests

Tags: api, http, python-requests

I am trying to POST an image with the requests module from my local client to a service (tillhub.com). Since the api documentation for posting images is missing (at least for me) some important aspects, I am trying to use the Google Chrome Dev Tools to figure out the neccessary parameters. When I upload an image directly from the dashboard, I can see that the following parameters for the header are used:
[image]

In addition that, I can see that the following form data is going to be passed:
[image]

I am trying to mimic the request from my local client with the following snippet:

```
import requests

headers = 
{'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryOVDXaA33W3zKicwR',
 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
 'Authorization': 'Bearer .......',
 'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'}

files= {'image': ("demo.jpg",open("demo.jpg", "rb"),'image/jpeg')}

requests.post(url=url,files=files, headers=headers).json()
```

which results in

```
{'status': 400,
 'msg': 'Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0',
 'request': {'host': 'api.tillhub.com',
  'id': '946f956c-efcf-48e8-aec8-44e16b118a4e'}}
```

Based on their [JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/tillhub/tillhub-sdk-javascript/blob/master/src/v0/images.ts) I can see that they just use for the content-type 'image/jpeg':

```
 async create (query: ImagesQuery, payload: FormData): Promise<ImagesResponse> {
    const uri = this.uriHelper.generateBaseUri(`/${query.subsystem}/${query.prefix}`)
    try {
      const response = await this.http
        .getClient()
        .post(uri, payload, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' } })
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was playing with your code block. I have removed the `content-type` after reading this [question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415084/multipart-data-post-using-python-requests-no-multipart-boundary-was-found).

```
import requests

headers ={'Authorization': 'Bearer ey......eU','cache-control': 'no-cache'}
files=dict(image=('demo.jpg', open("demo.jpg", "rb"),'image/jpeg'))

requests.post(url=url,files=files, headers=headers).json()
```

And it worked for me. Can you please try this?