# errors from api when using python requests module for file upload

Tags: python, python-requests

when i make the following request:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/endpoint \
  -F "file=filepath/example.zip" \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
```

everything works fine.
However, when i try to do the same in python:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080/endpoint"

files = {"file": open("example.zip", "rb")}
headers = {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

the api gives me an error. are these two code snippets not equivalent? thanks

Answer (score 1):

the issue was this:

[multipart data POST using python requests: no multipart boundary was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415084/multipart-data-post-using-python-requests-no-multipart-boundary-was-found)

it seems as though setting

```
headers = {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
```

caused the issue. i removed it and it works