# request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data error when using Python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to create a resource using python requests library but I end up getting the following error

> {"reason": "request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data"}

Here is my sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
    
import requests
import json


def create():
    url = "https://abc.xyz.com"
    endpoint = '/admin/v3/shared'

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "******"]
    }

    config = {
        "archive": "builtin://kinesis",
        "tenant": "tenant1",
        "namespace": "kinesis",
        "name": "kinesis",
        "parallelism": 1,
        "inputs": [
            "persistent://shared/kinesis/shared"
        ],
        "configs": {
            "credentials": "{\"accessKey\":\"******\",\"secretKey\":\"******"}",
            "endpoint": "kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
        }
    }
    config_json = json.dumps(config)

    response = requests.post(url + endpoint, headers=headers,
                             data=config_json)

    # Check the status code of the response
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return json.dumps(response.json())
    elif response.status_code == 400:
        return json.dumps(response.json())
    else:
        return json.dumps(response.json())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(create())
```

I tried adding Content-Type multi-part but it doesn't work. Also, I saw this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415084/multipart-data-post-using-python-requests-no-multipart-boundary-was-found) which recommends not to add Content-Type in the header. Any help here would be appreciated.