# Request must be multipart/mixed with json and photo without header

Tags: python, http, python-requests

How can I sent POST request in Python? Request must be multipart/mixed with json and photo without header. I try send this request with requests in python, but this package adds a description to the Data and the requests breaks the json into several parts. Example of a correct request's structure on [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvNV4.png). It is my code:

```
photo = open("photo.jpg", "rb")
file = {
    "Data": photo
}
new_card = {
    "AlternateId": "4558021a-4c29-5360-a511-08c59b52265c",
    "CreatedBy": "1",
    "Information": "test",
    "IsActive": True,
    "IsDeleted": False,
    "UserGroupId": 3,
    "PersonCardCategoryId": 3
}
r = requests.post("http://172.16.127.160:34015", auth=("1", "1"), data=new_card, files=file)
```

Updates:

Code:

```
r = requests.post("http://172.16.127.160:34015", auth=("1", "1"), json=new_card, files=file)
```

Now, WireShark shows me [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5p6y.png)

Comment: Read [post-a-multipart-encoded-file](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Comment: I read this site when I started do this programm. And all examples do not work in my programm...

Comment: Read this Answer [how to POST multipart ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26300042/7414759), last 3 Sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request with content-type 'multipart/mixed' with json and photo without header.

```
import requests
import json
from cStringIO import StringIO
headers = {
    '...': "...", 
    '...': "..."}
json = StringIO(json.dumps(new_card))
file = open('C:\\temp\\D.jpg', 'rb').read()
files = {"json": (None, json, "application/json; charset=UTF-8"), None: (None, file)}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:34015', files=files, headers=headers)
```

Discussion of this issue https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1736

Consider next thing - 'multipart/mixed' it is not necessary to specify in the content type in the header. The main thing is that there should be a boundary.
You can also build the query yourself, as shown here [Python Requests Multipart HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592553/python-requests-multipart-http-post)

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Request must be multipart/mixed with json and photo without header

Your Questions Example Code doesn't respect how `json` have to be passed:
To POST `json` do the following:

> [more-complicated-post-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)
>
> ```
> import json
> payload = {'some': 'data'}
> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), files=files)
> ```
>
> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be encoded automatically:
>
> ```
> payload = {'some': 'data'}
> r = requests.post(url, json=payload, files=files)
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but now Wireshark shows that there is no data in the request body(

Comment: done. If I change `data=json.dumps(...)` python freezes.

Comment: Sorry, now  I update the photos and they are different