# Python Requests - format data according to the given curl request

Tags: python, http, curl, httprequest, python-requests

```
 $ curl -F myfile=@myfilename -F 'data={"title":"some title","otherinfo" : "aabcdef"}' https://someurl
```

The above is the working and correct way for doing from terminal.

I tried to implement this in python using requests in this way :

```
files = {'myfile': open('myfilename', 'rb')}
data = {}

data['data'] = {
    'title' : 'some title',
    'otherinfo' : 'other info'
}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, auth=auth)
```

Here, the data is not reaching the destination properly, where am I wrong ?

Comment: What does it mean *is not reaching the destination properly*? What does server receive when you use curl and what does it receive when you use Requests?

Comment: when using curl, reaching correctly, but when using requests, the server not recognising data bcoz it wants the data to be in proper form. If u see from curl, data is like -F 'data=...' . I want its equivalent using requests. I tried sending the exact string 'data=..' like data="same as curl strng" but this requests not allowing like that, i tried json.dumps(data), but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `-F` argument curl sends data with `Content-Type` set to `multipart/form-data` whereas when you use `data` parameter Requests uses `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You should instruct Requests to send data with the right `Content-Type`. See [How to send a "multipart/form-data" with requests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12385179/95735) how to do this.