# Python Uploading Files using Requests. Server running PHP

Tags: python, file-upload

i have this situation where in i am uploading files to a server using Python. here is my python script. this uses apache2 certified requests library

```
 def Upload(self):
 Url = 'http://x.php'
 Payload = {
     'Location' : self.Location,
     'Version'  : self.Version,
     'Variant'  : self.Variant,
     }

 #employing requests
 File = {'file' : ('TestFile', open(self.Location, 'rb'))}
 response = requests.post(Url, files=File, data=Payload)
```

The data is received by an apache2 server running on ubuntu machine. I would want to know how to access the sent file from the PHP code and save it in the desired location. Can you please suggest the way to achieve this.

Is there any way like HTTP, where i can specify the that this is like  so, i can access using $_FILE["TestFile"]

Please help
-sreekanth

Comment: Fix your indentation please

Comment: well this is just a code snippet. But, I did have proper indentation

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send a "multipart/form-data" with requests in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python)