# POST multipart-form image with python through rest API call

Tags: python, image, post

I am relatively new to python and enjoying every day I program in it.  I have been looking around for a possible solution to figure out how to post an image in a multipart-form, binary format, with a form tag.  The API I am trying to call is expecting a binary image in a form. 
The request payload sample I have is:

```
----WebkitFormBoundaryM817iTBsSwXz0iv8
Content-Disposition: form-data, name="image"; filename="123BMW.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
----WebkitFormBoundaryM817iTBsXwxz0iv8
```

I have tried several ideas based on some basic requests examples.
Any ideas, thoughts or pointers on where to start looking for such a solution?

```
def Post_Image(urlPath, filePath, fileName): 
    url = urlPath headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'} 
    files = {'file':(fileName, open(filePath,'rb'))} 
    payload = {"Content-Disposition": "form-data", "name":fileName} 
    payload = urllib.urlencode(payload) 
    resp = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, files= files)
```

Comment: check this: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml this is useful.

Comment: have to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/1117099

Comment: Manoj and Syed,  Thanks for your input, I figure this out.

Comment: Any ideas? I have same problem now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're setting both the `data` and `files` parameters, this part of the code sample here:

```
payload = urllib.urlencode(payload) 
resp = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, files= files)
```

If both are present, *and* `data` value is a string, only it will be in the request. Drop it, and the files will be present.