# Python : Trying to POST form using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login a website for some scraping using Python and requests library, I am trying the following (which doesn't work):

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'username':'niceusername','password':'123456'}

In [12]: r = requests.post('https://admin.example.com/login.php',headers=headers,data=payload)
```

But nada, getting a redirect to the login page. Do I need to open a session? am I doing a wrong POST request, do I need to load the cookies?
or does session does that automatically?
I am lost here, some help and explanations are needed.

The website I'm trying to login is php, do I need to "capture the set-cookie and set the cookie header"? if so I have no idea how to do it.
The webpage is a form with the following (if it helps):
input :username' 'password'
'id':'myform', 'action':"login.php

Some extra information, maybe you can see what I'm missing here..

```
In [13]: r.headers
Out[13]: CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
 'set-cookie': 'PHPSESSID=v233mnt4malhed55lrpc5bp8o1; path=/',
  'expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'nginx',
   'connection': 'keep-alive', 'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
     'date': 'Tue, 24 Dec 2013 10:50:44 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html'})

In [14]: r.cookies
Out[14]: <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[Cookie(version=0, name='PHPSESSID',
 value='v233mnt4malhed55lrpc5bp8o1', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='admin.example.com',
  domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False,
   expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

I would really appreciate the help, thanks!

update, with answer thanks to atupal:

```
    import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'username':'usr','pass':'123'}
link    = 'https://admin.example.com/login.php'
session = requests.Session()
resp    = session.get(link,headers=headers)
# did this for first to get the cookies from the page, stored them with next line:
cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies))
resp    = session.post(link,headers=headers,data=payload,cookies =cookies)
#used firebug to check POST data, password, was actually 'pass', under 'net' in param.  
#and to move forward from here after is:
session.get(link)
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but didn't work in my case. Could you please take a look? Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248578/python-requests-module-to-verify-if-http-login-is-successful-or-not

Comment: Thanks for this - the cookie jar etc link integration was necessary for my use case - Strava data grabber beyond what the current API provides, in case anyone is searching for this in future.

Comment: Most of the below answers don't encode the password, so are insecure. A more modern approach would use `requests.post(authEndPoint, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(userName, password))`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use the [Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) object

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'username':'niceusername','password':'123456'}

session = requests.Session()
session.post('https://admin.example.com/login.php',headers=headers,data=payload)
# the session instance holds the cookie. So use it to get/post later.
# e.g. session.get('https://example.com/profile')
```

Comment: Hi atupal, i tried your answer, did resp=session.post(....). the resp.content tells that it's on the same login page.

Comment: @user2627775 That means you haven't logined successfully. Have you used firbug or other pacp tools capture package to determin what's data it sends?

Comment: i will check it now :)

Comment: it says:
Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded
pass 1234567
username usernamename
Source
username=1234567&pass=usernamename

Comment: @user2627775 So the param name you pass is not "password" but should "pass"?  just `{'username':'xx', 'pass': 'yy'}`

Comment: yes indeed. I know my question was simple and yet thanks allot atupal!! you made my day (after lots of tries), you got me on the right direction and now i know more than i knew before. so thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @atupal. I'm having similar problem here could you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248578/python-requests-module-to-verify-if-http-login-is-successful-or-not

Answer (score 21):

Send a POST request with content type = 'form-data':

```
import requests
files = {
    'username': (None, 'myusername'),
    'password': (None, 'mypassword'),
}
response = requests.post('https://example.com/abc', files=files)
```

Comment: what is None for?

Comment: File name. See this answer for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661

Answer (score 8):

I was having problems here (i.e. sending form-data whilst uploading a file) until I used the following:

```
files = {'file': (filename, open(filepath, 'rb'), 'text/xml'),
         'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="' + filename + '"',
         'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
```

That's the input that ended up working for me. In Chrome Dev Tools -> Network tab, I clicked the request I was interested in. In the Headers tab, there's a Form Data section, and it showed both the Content-Disposition and the Content-Type headers being set there.

I did NOT need to set headers in the actual requests.post() command for this to succeed (including them actually caused it to fail)