# Login to Website and get source code, getting SSL errors

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get a website's source data after logging in but am having trouble logging in to get to the source.  The url is *the* webpage I see after logging in.  I.e. if I login on chrome, I can use `url` to go to where I need to get the source data.

I keep getting multiple errors, primarily handshake errors:

"sslv3 alert handshake failure", "bad handshake", "urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError", and I think the primary error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\bwayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 441, in wrap_socket
>       cnx.do_handshake()
>
> File "C:\Users\bwayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1716, in do_handshake
>       self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
>
> File "C:\Users\bwayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1456, in _raise_ssl_error
>       _raise_current_error()
>
> File "C:\Users\bwayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
>       raise exception_type(errors)
>
> OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
import requests, sys
import ssl
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager


ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

class Ssl3HttpAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
url = "www.thewebsite.com"

def do_requests(url):
    payload = {'Username': 'myName', 'Password': 'myPass'} 
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.mount(url,Ssl3HttpAdapter())
        p = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)

def main(url):
    do_requests(url)


main(url)
```

How can I login? I've double and triple checked that the HTML names are correct:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the `user-agent` in your session? Maybe this website doesn't allow `python requests` as user-agent. And where exactly are you using `from OpenSSL import SSL`?

Comment: @nutmeg64 - How do I change the user-agent?  Also, I'm not - that was accidentally left in from other attempts I did, I'll remove that part.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759981/python-trying-to-post-form-using-requests) for a good example on how to send form data with `requests`. When you click this *url* in Chrome, does it redirect you? If it is, to what url? Maybe you should do the `POST` to that url instead?

Comment: @nutmeg64 - When I go to the `url` in my code, it goes to the site I want - logged in and everything.  I added `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/61.0'}` and did `p = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)`,  but that doesn't seem to do anything...same errors come up.  Also, I am able to use Python to open the tab in chrome successfully.  If there's a way to use an open Chrome session to save the URL of the active tab, I'm open to that too I suppose.

Comment: When you do it from your browser it is already logged in because you did it once already and your browser remembers it. Try to logout of that site and go to that url again.

Comment: @nutmeg64 - Logged out and closed Chrome. Opened chrome, tried to go to URL (just pasting it in Address Bar) - brings me to the login screen, which it should.  And then, I ran the python code (with your above suggestions) and still same errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156132/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-nutmeg64).

Comment: Per the chat - it's been decided it's a *server-side* issue, and not with my code. I'm not sure if I should close or delete, so let me know what to do!