# form data request with many elements with same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

I do need to create a long parameter list for a web page post which is not a dictionary based cause of multiple same keys.

Chromium shows this string as form data in the original request

```
p_action=RUN&p_mode=1&p_exec_mode=&p_page_url=&p_redirect_url=&p_reference_path=&p_arg_names=_title&p_arg_values=ARRAYSTART&p_arg_values=kschulz&p_arg_values=ARRAYEND&p_arg_names=reqnum&p_arg_values=ARRAYSTART&p_arg_values=0&p_arg_values=ARRAYEND&p_arg_names=_orderby_ord_1&p_arg_values=ASC
```

.... much more entries follow.

I know this is a crazy form data but I can not change this.
 `p_arg_names` is used multiple times and sometimes followed by multiple `p_arg_value` entries. Array Start and Array Stop are even existing... So I need the right order too.

`params=dict`... can not work here.

How can I provide `requests.push(URL,DATA)` a longer pure string without losing the

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: where is your code? there is no method like `requests.push(URL,DATA)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : Trying to POST form using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759981/python-trying-to-post-form-using-requests)

Answer (score 3):

The params dict *can* work here, give it a list of the values.., eg:

```
r = requests.get('http://example.com', {'something': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

(use .get/.put/.post/.patch - or whatever it is you mean by .push above)

The server will receive a request such as:

```
"GET /?something=1&something=2&something=3&something=4&something=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 396 "-" "python-requests/2.18.4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `requests` module

```
import requests

request.post('http://127.0.0.1/8000/', params= {'p_arg_names': ['a', 'b']})
```

Results in

> Post http://127.0.0.1/8000/?p_arg_names=a&p_arg_names=b HTTP/1.