# cannot create flask login test function

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask-login

I have a login function with user and pass parameters that returns a token. I'am using flask.
Now i need a test case to test my function, i am lost here.
Neve done testing and i can't come up with the solution.
I need a test case that verifies a token was created when the login is made.
Any help?

````
def login():

    user = request.form['user']
    passwd = request.form['passwd']

    test = ldap.bind_user(user, passwd)
    if test is None or passwd == '':
        response = jsonify(message='Invalid Credentials')
        return response ,401

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token), 200```
````

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20760055/8375783 answer how to post a form via `requests`. With that you can try login attempts with various data set then check the response.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days i finally manage to come up with the solution.
I checked if access_token was in the response.data

````
    def test_token_sent(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        response = tester.post(
            '/login',
            data =dict(user="hermes", passwd ="hermes"),
            follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertIn(b'access_token', response.data)```
````