# how to get post request on this website? https://www.upiqrcode.com/iban-generator/de/germany

Tags: python

how to get post request on this website?

here I have trouble getting post requests such as urls and post data, because I use a smart phone so I can't get it, anyone can get it, the url and post data are okay.

this is the website

https://www.upiqrcode.com/iban-generator/de/germany

I want the data section to be filled in like this when on the website

Select Country: Germany

Bank Code (8 Digits .i.e. 37040044 ): 37040044

Bank Account No. ( 10 digits i.e. 0532013000): 0532013034

```
import requests

url = ""

datas = {}

GetInfo = requests.post(url, data=datas)

decodeResponse = GetInfo.content.decode("utf-8")

print(decodeResponse)
```

Comment: When you run your Python script, what was the _trouble_? I got an error `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?`. You should [edit] your question and add this.

Comment: I only asked to get post requests such as api and post data on the website I mentioned earlier, that's all.

Comment: can you get it, by opening developer mode in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you define the `url` properly by assigning the given URL:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.upiqrcode.com/iban-generator/de/germany"
datas = {}
GetInfo = requests.post(url, data=datas)
decodeResponse = GetInfo.content.decode("utf-8")

print(decodeResponse)
```

You would end up getting HTML as response, which correctly prints on console.

#### Record the form-submission and watch POST request in browser

Instead, figure out how and where the form-data is POSTed. Do this by opening the browsers Developer Console (usually <kbd>F12</kbd>) and viewing the **Network** tab, before clicking submit button (here "Calculate") on the form.

[image: Firefox Network Monitor to show POST request]

You can even right-click on the request there an **Copy** > as **CURL**. Then paste that in a text-editor or on the command-line to reproduce.

```sh
curl 'https://www.upiqrcode.com/get-iban-number' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/0.0 (OS) Gecko/20210808 Firefox/0.0' \
-H 'Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
-H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
-H 'Origin: https://www.upiqrcode.com' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Referer: https://www.upiqrcode.com/iban-generator/de/germany' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
-H 'Sec-GPC: 1' \
--data-raw 'country=DE&bank=37040044&branch=&account=0532013000&ip=0.0.0.0'
```

Note: I have broken into several lines for readability (thus the `\` at line ends). For privacy protection I have anonymized data like User-Agent and IP in the request above.

Even when anonymized like this, the request sent via [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) on the command-line, you get a response (HTML snippet) with the expected **IBAN**:

```html
<h4 class="text-center text-success">IBAN Electronic Format :DE89370400440532013000</h4><h4 class="text-center text-success">IBAN Paper Format :DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 </h4>
```

#### Reproduce in Python

Now you can rebuild this POST-request in Python.

What we need is:

- some request-headers like `'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`
- the posted data: `'country=DE&bank=37040044&branch=&account=0532013000&ip=0.0.0.0'`

Comment: why don't the results come out

Comment: this part is not coming out, do you have any suggestions.

<h4 class="text-center text-success">IBAN Electronic Format :DE89370400440532013000</h4><h4 class="text-center text-success">IBAN Paper Format :DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 </h4>

the result above does not come out

Comment: @NancySavchenko Sure, this part is coming out of the CURL request. I left it to you, to code the request in Python. A tutorial for [POSTing forms with requests](https://realpython.com/python-requests/) or [research on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759981/python-trying-to-post-form-using-requests)

Comment: oh now the results are out, thank you for your help

Comment: @NancySavchenko Welcome, that's what Stackoverflow is about. Please contribute back and try improving your question (title, formatting, spelling/grammar, etc.), so it can be found and helps others ️

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Mr.hc_dev asnwer to know how i got URL

```
import requests

url = "https://www.upiqrcode.com/get-iban-number"
replace_with_your_ip = ""
datas = {
    "country":"DE",
    "bank":"37040044",
    "account":"0532013034",
    "ip":replace_with_your_ip,
}

GetInfo = requests.post(url, data=datas)

decodeResponse = GetInfo.content.decode("utf-8")

print(decodeResponse)
```

To remove HTML content

```
import re

def remove_tags(text):
    comp = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')
    return comp.sub('', text)

print(remove_tags(decodeResponse))
```

Or with BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(decodeResponse,"html.parser")
for i in soup.find_all("h4"):
    print(i.text)
```

**O/P**

```
IBAN Electronic Format :___ Paper Format :___
```

Comment: this part is not coming out, do you have any suggestions.

<h4 class="text-center text-success">IBAN Electronic Format :DE89370400440532013000</h4><h4 class="text-center text-success">IBAN Paper Format :DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 </h4>

the result above does not come out

Comment: Can you please tell output you are getting?

Comment: the results are indeed out, but just plain html, no results are displayed, but the results below don't come out.

<h4 class="text-center text-success">IBAN Electronic Format :DE89370400440532013000</h4><h4 class="text-center text-success">IBAN Paper Format :DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 </h4>

Comment: oh now the results are out, thank you for your help