# Using an API with python

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

Here is the API from [this website](https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api-doc/adresse)

```
curl -X POST -F data=@path/to/file.csv https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/
```

I would like to know how to use this in python.

What I currently know is that from the same website, we also have this API

```
curl "https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=8+bd+du+port"
```

With python we can do:

```
import requests
ADDOK_URL = 'http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/'
response = requests.get(ADDOK_URL, params={'q': '8 bd du port', 'limit': 5})
response.json()
```

But with

```
curl -X POST -F data=@path/to/file.csv https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/
```

I have to specify a path of csv file. And I also don't know what are `-X POST -F`.

Comment: You seem to have the building blocks together. Without an API description and/or task what you wnat to do, I don't see how to help you, or what the question is ...

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. Assuming the GET returns HTTP 200 then your call to response.json() will produce the desired results

Comment: Just a guess here, but judging by the `curl` command, I think you should replace `{'q': '8 bd du port',` with `{'q': '8+bd+du+port',`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Trying to POST form using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759981/python-trying-to-post-form-using-requests)

Comment: From the `curl` command `-X POST` is the equivalent of `requests.post()`, and `-F data=@path/to/file.csv`  I guess you can pass `data={'data': '@path/to/file.csv'}` to `post()`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I don't know what type of response you are expercting. I got no errors and some values in a test as a result.

```
import requests

files = [
    ('data', ('file', open('your path to .csv file', 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream'))
]

response = requests.post("https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/", files=files, params={'q': '8 bd du port', 'limit': 5})

print(response.text)
```

This is a POST request, you used a GET request, so use `requests.post` and not `requests.get`.