# Making a timetable app for my university schedule

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-post

I am trying to make a timetable app for my university schedule since our school website does not provide a visualized timetable, rather it provides something like this:

[description of registered courses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAwmF.png)

With this in mind, I have already started on this project and listed out the steps I need to take in order to complete it.

1. Write a function that logs into the school website
2. Write a function that saves the HTML file that includes the description of registered courses
3. Write a function that scrapes the data from the HTML file and save the necessary data into fields such as COURSE_ID, COURSE_LOCATION, COURSE_STARTTIME, COURSE_ENDTIME, etc..
4. Write a function that builds a visualized timetable with these fields as parameters

Of these four generalized steps, I have completed the third step, which is the data scraping portion.
However, I have run into some problems and could not figure out how to do step 1.
I was wondering if anyone could help me out here.

To provide more specific details, the school website link is https://ics.twu.ca/ICS/.
From here, I do not know how to write a script that can request the URL and make a POST request with username and password.

I am writing this program in Python.

Comment: Please re-take the intro tour, especially [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Perhaps first, see the meta-post ["Can someone help me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: `I have run into some problems` what are these ?

Comment: the main problem is that the csrf verification fails when I do GET requests

Answer (score 0):

The authentication request is a POST on `https://ics.twu.ca/ICS/`. Get all `input` name/value pairs from the page, use a session to record the cookies. This form uses `multipart/form-data` so use [`files`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) parameter.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://ics.twu.ca/ICS/"

username = "your_username"
password = "your_password"

session = requests.Session()

r = session.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

payload = dict((x, (None, y)) for x, y in [
    (i["name"], i.get("value"))
    for i in soup.find_all("input")
])

payload["userName"] = username
payload["password"] = password

print(payload)

r = session.post(url, files = payload)

print(r.text)
```

In the above `payload` is a dictionnary of the input value with tuple of `(None, value)` since we don't need the filename variable (we are not uploading files but just sending values). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23131823/2614364)

If this is not working add headers such as user-agent