# How to send a 'multipart/form-data' with requests, without files in Python

Tags: python, file, python-requests, multipartform-data, content-type

I want to send a 'multipart/form-data' dictionary data without files

```
headers = {'key':'value', 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}
data = {'api_key':'api_value', ... }

response = request.post('API_URL', headers=headers, data=data)
```

but API response is:

```
FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

so I changed `'multipart/form-data' -> 'multipart/form-data; boundary=____sample'`
This code also didn't work. It didn't recognize the parameters.

How can I send 'multipart/form-data' requests without files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how python works with requests. You can try this accepted answers or any which is suitable

[python requests - POST Multipart/form-data without filename in HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120974/python-requests-post-multipart-form-data-without-filename-in-http-request)