# Write geojson string into a tuple for a requests.post method with file parameter

Tags: file, post, tuples, postgis, geojson

I have to submit geojsons from a Postgres (PostGIS) database with requests.post() method and the files argument:

x = requests.post(url, files = myfiles)

However, I need to avoid writing all my geojsons to a file and then read them again (the cloud environment where the PostsGres is running does not allow me to store files).

I read that a workaround could be to populate the file parameter with a tuple (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23131823/16214039). However, I cannot manage to store my geojson strings into a tuple, since the string will be sliced/splitted due to the '' and comma's in the geojson string when I try to convert it to a tuple element. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: You can use triple quotes `"""` around the literal if you want to secure all regular single `'` and double quotes `"` inside the string. If that's not what you had in mind, please attach an example where the string in your tuple gets split against your intention.

Comment: Hi @Zegarek, thanks. Worked! I used triple single quotes and that did not work... But the triple double quotes worked.