# How do I replicate a `curl` with `-F` in Python 3?

Tags: python, http, curl, python-requests

I have this `curl`:

```sh
curl -v "http://some.url" \
    -X PUT \
    -H "X-API-Key: API_KEY" \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
    -F "logo=@the_logo.png;type=image/png"
```

And I am trying to replicate this with Python.
What I have tried so far is:

```py
import requests


with open("the_logo.png", "rb") as file_obj:
   data = file_obj.read()
requests.put(
    "http://some.url",
    files={"logo": ("the_logo.png", data, "image/png")},
    headers={
        "X-API-Key": "API_KEY",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
```

But for some reason the `curl` above works, while the Python code does not and the server replies with a `422`.

How can I make Python replicate what `curl` does?

Comment: Have you sniffed the HTTP requests to see how they differ?

Comment: BTW, you should be able to have `file_obj` itself be in the `data` location in the tuple (if you haven't read from it and the pointer is still at the front of the file, so you'd need to take out the `data = file_obj.read()` line).

Comment: try `files={"logo": ("the_logo.png", open('the_logo.png', 'rb'), "image/png")}` once.

Comment: have you checked out http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html?

Comment: @Tarique's suggestion matches with this answer, except using POST instead of PUT: [How to upload file with python requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567429/1431750)

Comment: Tarique's comment is what I see from https://curl.trillworks.com/#python

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How would I go with that? It seems that Python/requests does not provide the raw data sent

Comment: @Tarique I tried that but I get the same problem

Comment: The word "sniff" implies use of a packet sniffer -- Wireshark, tcpdump, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [some reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python), it appears that the trick is to **NOT** set `Content-Type` in the headers when using [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and the `files` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

So, `curl -F ...` is basically emulating submitting a form.

> -F, --form <name=content>
>
> (HTTP  SMTP  IMAP) For HTTP protocol family, this lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to  POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.

You can replicate this in Python using the [`requests` module](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) (note that you will need to install it - e.g., `pip3 install requests`):

```
import requests

with open("the_logo.png", "rb") as file:
    file_content = file.read()

response = requests.put(
    "http://localhost:8080",
    files={"logo": file_content},
    headers={
        "X-API-Key": "API_KEY",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
)
```

Or, although not really straightforward, using the built-in [`urllib.request` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html):

```
import io
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import uuid

with open("the_logo.png", "rb") as file:
    file_content = file.read()

boundary = uuid.uuid4().hex.encode("utf-8")

buffer = io.BytesIO()
buffer.write(b"--" + boundary + b"\r\n")
buffer.write(b"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"logo\"; filename=\"logo\"\r\n")
buffer.write(b"\r\n")
buffer.write(file_content)
buffer.write(b"\r\n")
buffer.write(b"--" + boundary + b"--\r\n")
data = buffer.getvalue()

request = Request(url="http://localhost:8080", data=data, method="PUT")
request.add_header("X-API-Key", "API_KEY")
request.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
request.add_header("Content-Length", len(data))
request.add_header("Content-Type", f"multipart/form-data; boundary={boundary.decode('utf-8')}")
with urlopen(request) as response:
    response_body = response.read().decode("utf-8")
```

If you use for example netcat to listen to the used port, you should see that both `curl -F ...` and the above scripts generate something like the following:

```
$ nc -l -p 8080
PUT / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
X-Api-Key: API_KEY
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: [DATA_LENGTH]
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=[GENERATED_BOUNDARY]
Connection: close

--[GENERATED_BOUNDARY]
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="logo"; filename="logo"

[PNG_BYTES]
--[GENERATED_BOUNDARY]--
```

**NOTE:** For a more complete `urllib.request` implementation see https://pymotw.com/3/urllib.request/#uploading-files