# Python convert curl command to urllib.request

Tags: python, curl, request, urllib, pycurl

I would like to convert my curl to urllib.request command to python, the curl command:

```
curl -v -i -X POST http://api.textart.io/img2txt.json --form image=@path/to/dir/file.jpg
```

my code:

```py
import json
from urllib import request, parse

data = parse.urlencode({
    "image": open("path/to/dir/file.jpg", "rb")
}).encode()

req = request.Request("http://api.textart.io/img2txt.json")
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
response = json.loads(request.urlopen(req, data).read())
response = json.dumps(response, indent=4)

print(response)
```

response:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at
 webmaster@api.textart.io to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

whereas with curl that works, help please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload Image using POST form data in Python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104107/upload-image-using-post-form-data-in-python-requests)

Comment: thanks but now I've a new error, I edit my answer

Comment: if you would use `requests` then you could use portal https://curlconverter.com/ to convert it.

Comment: you could use address https://httpbin.org/post in `curl` and `python` - it should send back all information which you send to this url - and you could compare results to see differences.

Comment: I think I see one problem - in Python you send `GET` instead of `POST`

Comment: That works with curlconverter.com thanks!

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/ send post

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77881652/2128591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would use module `requests` instead of `urllib` then you could use portal http://curlconverter.com to convert it. But sometimes it may create code with mistakes.

---

If you would use program [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test web page then it also has function to generate code in different languages - and it should have function to generate for `urllib` in Python.

---

You can also use portal https://httpbin.org (and url httpbin.org/post) to test request in `curl`and `python`. Portal sends back all data which it gets in request and you can compare what you send in `curl` and `python`.

---

But I used on Linux local program [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) to simulate server and see `raw` request.

```
nc -l localhost 8080
```

and then test `curl` and `urllib` with `http://localhost:8080`

and created this code which should work with `api.textart.io`

```
from urllib import request
import json
    
file_data = open("path/image.jpg", "rb").read()

BOUNDARY = b'------------------------360768b014779354'

data = [
    b'--' + BOUNDARY,
    b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"',
    b'Content-Type: image/jpeg',
    b'',
    file_data,
    b'--' + BOUNDARY + b'--',
    b'',
]

data = b'\r\n'.join(data)
#print(data)

url = "http://api.textart.io/img2txt.json"
#url = "https://httpbin.org/post"
#url = 'http://localhost:8080'

req = request.Request(url)

req.add_header("Content-Type", 'multipart/form-data; boundary={}'.format(BOUNDARY.decode())), 
#req.add_header("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
#req.add_header("Accept", "*/*")

response = json.loads(request.urlopen(req, data).read())
response = json.dumps(response, indent=4)
print(response)
```