# Python requests.post multipart/form-data

Tags: python, post, python-requests, multipartform-data

I have to use a REST API to upload files and information to a server. That API uses a multipart-form, but I cannot seem to be able to use it correctly.

Here is the information I use according to the API documentation.

Form Parameters:

- description – A short description of the distribution.
- release_notes_url – A url pointing to the release notes.
- zip_file – The ZIP file containing the distribution files.

Example request:

```
POST /api/v1/distribution HTTP/1.1
Host: api.company.onbe
Authorization: t=...
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZayrf7leHxinyQsX


------WebKitFormBoundaryZayrf7leHxinyQsX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="release_notes_url"
http://releases/3.0.0/release_notes_3_0_0.pdf
------WebKitFormBoundaryZayrf7leHxinyQsX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"
This is the new distribution!
------WebKitFormBoundaryZayrf7leHxinyQsX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="zip_file"; filename="BackEnd-3.0.0.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
------WebKitFormBoundaryZayrf7leHxinyQsX--
```

I tried several things, like the following code for example, but I keep getting bad request errors from the server.

```
import requests

file= open('BackEnd-3.0.0.zip','r').read()

url = 'api.company.onbe/api/v1/distribution'

payload = {
  'description' :'Some desc',
  'release_notes_url':'Someurl.pdf',
  'zip_file': file
  }

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The docs have an example http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

You should really start there for simple use cases.

This answer also explains using files and data together.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/1182891

Here is a working example for people who want cut-n-paste code. httpbin returns a json data structure describing the request you made do it. In this case you can see that `files` contains the file data posted and `form` contains the form vars. `headers` shows that it was indeed a `multipart/form-data` request.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': ('report.csv', 'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}
>>> response = requests.post(url, data={
...   'description' :'Some desc',
...   'release_notes_url':'Someurl.pdf'
...   }, files=files)
>>> pprint(response.json())
{u'args': {},
 u'data': u'',
 u'files': {u'file': u'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n'},
 u'form': {u'description': u'Some desc', u'release_notes_url': u'Someurl.pdf'},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate',
              u'Content-Length': u'394',
              u'Content-Type': u'multipart/form-data; boundary=ebf9f03029db4c2799ae16b5428b06bd',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.10.0'},
 u'json': None,
 u'origin': u'73.0.41.38',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post'}
```

**Enjoy**!