# How do I solve this AttributeError with Request's multi-part form-data POST?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to post files to my `graphql` endpoint @ scaphold.io.  I normally write `Javascript`, but I have to translate this particular operation into `Python`.

The command to do so with `curl` looks like this ([from their docs](https://scaphold.io/docs/?shell#uploading-files)):

```
curl -v https://us-west-2.api.scaphold.io/graphql/scaphold-graphql \
  -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
  -F 'query=mutation CreateFile($input: CreateFileInput!) { createFile(input: $input) { changedFile { id name blobMimeType blobUrl user { id username } } } }' \
  -F 'variables={ "input": { "name": "Profile Picture", "userId": "VXNlcjoxMA==", "blobFieldName": "myBlobField" } };type=application/json' \
  -F myBlobField=@mark-zuckerberg.jpg
```

Where the `blobFieldName` prop in `variables` matches the `Form` field name that holds the file to upload.

Using `Requests`, I've gotten this far:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

url = 'https://us-west-2.api.scaphold.io/graphql/scaphold-graphql'
multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
        "query":"mutation CreateFile($input: CreateFileInput!) { createFile(input: $input) { changedFile { id name blobMimeType blobUrl user { id username } } } }",
        "variables": { "input": { "name": "Profile Picture", "userId": "VXNlcjoxMA==", "blobFieldName": "myBlobField" } },
        "type":'application/json',
        "myBlobField": ('example.jpg', open('example.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg' )
        }      
)
req_headers = {'Content-Type':multipart_data.content_type, 'Authorization':'Bearer myreallylongkey'}

r = requests.post(url, data=multipart_data, headers=req_headers)
```

Unfortunately this is met with the `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-gql.py", line 38, in <module>
    "myBlobField": ('example.jpg', open('example.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg' )
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 119, in __init__
    self._prepare_parts()
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 240, in _prepare_parts
    self.parts = [Part.from_field(f, enc) for f in self._iter_fields()]
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 488, in from_field
    body = coerce_data(field.data, encoding)
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 466, in coerce_data
    return CustomBytesIO(data, encoding)
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 529, in __init__
    buffer = encode_with(buffer, encoding)
  File "/home/bmp/code/wayhome/python-phash/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 410, in encode_with
    return string.encode(encoding)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I'm afraid I'm not Pythonic enough to grok this error, but I've eliminated a few suspects:

- Translating a simple `query` from `curl` to `Python` works fine, so I know it isn't permissions, etc.
- Using a different file, of the `plain/text` flavor, fails w/ the same error
- Using a tuple-of-tuples instead of a `dict` for `fields` ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35974071))has no effect

Comment: curl converters: http://curl.trillworks.com/ and https://shibukawa.github.io/curl_as_dsl/index.html

Comment: see your last link - they use tuple with `files=`, not with `data=`

Comment: @furas thanks, those converters are awesome (esp first one).  Just a note if anyone else tries them:  the second converter only supports python 3, and the first converter appears to incorrectly truncate any string with a `=` character.  otherwise, its code looks correct.  re: `files` vs `data`, I believe when using `MultpartEncoder`, the param changes to `data`. I can say that `data` worked when implementing the solution in the accepted answer, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your example , it seems that you are passing "variables" as a dictionary but instead it should be a string. Change

```
        "variables": { "input": { "name": "Profile Picture", "userId": "VXNlcjoxMA==", "blobFieldName": "myBlobField" } },
```

to

```
        "variables": '{ "input": { "name": "Profile Picture", "userId": "VXNlcjoxMA==", "blobFieldName": "myBlobField" } }',
```

Please note the use to single quotes to make it a string
EDIT :: from the code of MultipartEncoder, MultipartEncoder tries to run .encode(...) method on the values. .encode(...) comes with strings. Because the datatype of value of key "variables" is dict, .encode(...) seems to be failing on it.