# HTTP form-encoding payload with nested arrays

Tags: python

I'm working with a third-party HTTP API like this:

```
curl https://secure.phabricator.com/api/maniphest.edit \
    -d "api.token=${API_TOKEN}" \
    -d "transactions[0][type]=subscribers.add" \
    -d "transactions[0][value][0]=${OWN_USER_PHID}" \
    -d "transactions[0][value][1]=${ANOTHER_USER_PHID}"
```

Basically it's a POST request with a request body like this (if written in Python syntax):

```
{"api.token": "...", "transactions": [{"type": "...", "value": ["...", "..."]}]
```

You can see that `transactions` is a nested array.

How do I encode such payload in Python? I'm using [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) to make the request if that matters.

Comment: this is a get request right?

Comment: `POST`. See the `curl` command, with `-d` argument. Let me edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: You need to json encode the python dictonary. So `import json` and then `request.post(url, data = json.dumps(body))`

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35974071/4110233

Comment: Thanks but the request body should be form-encoded. See the `curl` command in the question. The JSON (or Python dict) format is only for showing the structure of the request body.

Comment: See the link! Its for form-encoded version

Comment: Solution on `request`  or `server` ? Cheap is on `request` ! Change your request type/pattern.

Comment: I have no control over the API. It's a third-party API.