# Scraping data from AJAX website

Tags: jquery, ajax, python-3.x, request

[image]I am trying scrape data from a AJAX web interface site. Link to that website is as follows:

https://dps.psx.com.pk/

To do so I used the following code:

```
import requests

request_url = 'https://dps.psx.com.pk/webpages/history_bySymbol.php?op=4'
data = {'sday': '01', 'mth':'10', 'yr':'2012','symcode':'ENGRO'}  
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/61.0.3163.79 Chrome/61.0.3163.79 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.post(request_url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Now the problem is when I print the text I am unable to get data which is supposed to be generated by entering 4 parameters.

What might be wrong with the code?

Edit: Issue is that when I open the above webpage, on top there is a drop down menu for market data, from there I select historical data. Link in the chrome bar remains the same since it is an AJAX web interface.
My goal is to scrape historical data for that I am using above mentioned code. Using chrome's developer tools I looked at what ajax key was added when I requested for historical data. From there I found out it took four parameters as mentioned in the above code (XHR subsection to Headers). I expect that when I run the code it should provide me with historical data somewhere in r.text, but it doesn't. I need the data as shown in the image. I expected that above code to give these values but it didn't.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I've made edits. I don't get any error its just that I expect  the last line to contain my inquired data (somewhere in between html it prints), but it does not contain any data.

Answer (score 1):

```
payload = {'sday':'03','mth':'10','yr':'2017'}

r = requests.post(url='https://dps.psx.com.pk/webpages/history_byDate1.php', data=payload, headers ={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
```

This worked perfectly and gave results which I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You must send files instead of data. Take a look:

```
response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', files=dict(foo='bar'))
```

By using the files this will force the requests lib to use formdata instead

Also, below is the correct url. I think.

```
https://dps.psx.com.pk/webpages/history_bySymbol_data.php?op=4
```

Comment: The script runs properly but when it prints in the last line. I can see an error Your requrest has been rejected by the following cause: <br><br>
    <i style="color:#FF3300">Day is required <BR></i>

Comment: Then I changed 'sday' to Day but the same error  persist.

Comment: changes I made are as follow: data = {'Day': '01', 'Month':'10', 'Year':'2012','Symbol':'Engro CorpXD'}

Comment: I see in postman they only accept multipart/formdata. I got it to work using postman in the form-data section. Dont use a simple ajax and json.

Comment: Since I am new to python I can't get what postman is and where do I need to make changes. if you can kindly guide me where do I need to make change? Or if you can suggest a tutorial or guide that would help me with it.

Comment: I am not familiar with python either. If you like you can ask another question on stackoverflow on how to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate your above comment on mutlipart/formdata? and what exactly the problem is?

Comment: From here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python. I believe I've passed a multipart encoded data since my data is in form of dict.

Comment: I editied my answer. But if you use files variable instead of data it will send multipart.formdata instead. This is not tested so you may need to play with it a little.

Comment: Perfect. But I did it with another way I posted request through requests module and then I used beautifulsoup4 to parse which resolved my issue.

Comment: That is great. I am interested in your solution. Please share in your question or post an answer to this question.