# How can I post image and text MultipartForm on python3 and `requests`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm porting code from NodeJS to python3.
I want to post image binary data and text.
How can I do it ? Thank you.

NodeJS

```
filePath = "xxx.jpeg"
text = "xxx"
return chakram.request("POST", "http://xxx",
     { "multipart" : [
           { "body" : fs.createReadStream(filePath),
             "Content-Type" : "image/jpeg",
             "Content-Disposition" : "name='file'; filename='" + filePath + "'"
           },
           { "body" : JSON.stringify(this.RequestData(text)),
             "Content-Type" : "application/specified-content-type-xxx"
           }
       ],
       "headers" : {
           "Authorization" : "xxx"
       }
     })
```

My Wrong Python Code with `requests`:

```
filePath = "xxx.jpeg"
text = "xxx"
headers = {
    "Authorization" : "xxx"
}

binary_data = None
with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
    binary_data = fp.read()

request_body = {
    "text": text,
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "user1"
    }
}
files = {
    "file": (filePath, binary_data, 'image/jpeg'),
    "": ("", request_body, "application/specified-content-type-xxx")
}
resp = requests.post("http://xxx", files=files, headers=headers)
```

I got 500 error.

Comment: Have you tried to set `content type` in your headers ?

Comment: NodeJS code has no content type in headers. So I think content type is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Files are supported in python3 requests module, [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files). This should work out for you.

```
import requests

url = "http://xxx"

# just set files to a list of tuples of (form_field_name, file_info)
multiple_files = [
        ('images', ('xxx.jpeg', open('xxx.jpeg', 'rb'), 'image/png')),
        ('images', ('bar.png', open('bar.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'))
]

text_data = {"key":"value"}
headers = {
    "Authorization" : "xxx",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
r = requests.post(url, files=multiple_files, data=text_data, headers=headers)
r.text
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to specify text's content type `specified-content-type-xxx`. Do you know how can I do it?  I modified the question code a bit.

Comment: Should go inside headers. As per explanation here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests, `Using the json parameter in the request will change the Content-Type in the header to application/json.` it suggests, that content type should go in headers.

Comment: Hmm... it didn't work. the request_body is indeed Json format, but I need to set "application/specified-content-type-xxx" because of API.   
I set "application/specified-content-type-xxx" in my header, but it didn't work too. I got 500 error.

Comment: is it the status on response or this code is breaking. if response is having 500, then can you check what message is there in response.text.

Comment: Thank you, it says `{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError"
  }
}`

Comment: You would want to check the service you are hitting, double check the payload, and adhere to docs. If it's a third party service, and you can get some customer support, you should check it out too. I feel you are missing `name` here `{ "body" : JSON.stringify(this.RequestData(text)),
             "Content-Type" : "application/specified-content-type-xxx"
           }` , as the service might want to receive this data under some parameter name. Apologies, this might not have solved out your problem still.

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness. I changed the way I ask questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268471/et-me-know-how-can-i-send-multipart-form-dat-data-below-on-python3

Answer (score 1):

I use the Python3 library `urllib.request` and it works perfectly for me. I also use a private key and certificate to upload files with SSL authentication. I show you how to do it in `Python3` and its equivalent with the `cURL` command.

`Bash` version:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

KEY="my_key.pem"
CERT="my_cert.pem"
PASSWORD="XXXXXXX"
URL="https://put_here_your_host.com"
FILE="my_file.txt" # or .pdf, .tar.gz, etc.

curl -k --cert $CERT:$PASSWORD --key $KEY $URL -X POST -H "xxx : xxx, yyy: yyy" -T $FILE
```

`Python3` version:

```py
import ssl
import urllib.request

# Set global
key = 'my_key.pem'
cert = 'my_cert.pem'
password = 'XXXXXXX'
url = 'https://put_here_your_host.com'
file = 'my_file.txt' # or .pdf, .tar.gz, etc.

# Security block. You can skip this block if you do not need it.
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.load_cert_chain(cert, keyfile=key, password=password)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=context))
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

# Set request with headers.
headers = {
    'xxx' : 'xxx',
    'yyy': 'yyy'
}
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)

# Post your file.
urllib.request.urlopen(request, open(file, 'rb').read())
```

I hope it helps you.