# Unable to send `multipart/form-data` request with python requests module

Tags: java, python, spring, python-requests

I have Java spring server that requires the `Content-Type` of the requests being sent to the server to be `multipart/form-data`.

I can correctly send requests to the server with postman:

[image]

[image]

However, I got `The current request is not a multipart request` error when trying to send the request with `requests` module in python3.

My python code is:

```
import requests

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer auth_token'
}

data = {
  'myKey': 'myValue'
}

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/apiUrl', data=data, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

If I add `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` to the header of the request, the error message then becomes `Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`.

How can I make the same request as postman sends with python?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22974646/6890912

Comment: @blhsing   I'm not sending a file. I send texts.

Comment: Then what's the point of using `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` if you're not actually sending files?

Comment: @dmitryro I also want to the answer of your question. But the server was designed by someone else in my company many years ago. And that person has left the company.

Comment: Then probably the way the request is sent has to change so it will be a regular payload with POST, not multipart - something to change in POSTMAN at the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`requests`'s author thinks this situation is not pythonic, so `requests` doesn't support this usage natively.

You need to use `requests_toolbelt` which is an extension maintained by members of the requests core development team, [doc](http://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html#streaming-multipart-data-encoder), example:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={'field0': 'value', 'field1': 'value',
            'field2': ('filename', open('file.py', 'rb'), 'text/plain')}
    )

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=m,
                  headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```