# Post video to Facebook Page with Facebook SDK

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to post a video from url to my Facebook page. Is there any way for it, I already be able to post Images but seems like it's no way for video?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to post a video from url to my Facebook page. Is there any way for it, I already be able to post Images but seems like it's no way for video?

That is correct, videos can not be uploaded by specifying a video URL.

You need to perform an actual HTTP upload in `multipart/form-data` format.

Comment: Can you give me more detail to go, I got stuck all day for it til now. Thanks ^

Comment: What research have you done so far on this, what have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/ should help get you started.