# Create a task with attachments in Asana using Asana api

Tags: python, asana, asana-api

I am trying to send an image using Asana's API but it just attaches a blank file.
This is the code I have been using.

```
client.attachments.create_on_task(task_id=123456789,file_content="Url_of_file",file_name='Name_of_File',file_content_type="image/jpeg")
```

I have tried using different file formats like .txt and .png but for some reason the Asana API is blocking my requests.It just posts a black image on Asana.
I have tried to convert the file to base64 as well but it still doesn't work

In this original documentation(below), it shows that we need to pass two arguments;one for the file's content and the other for file itself ('file').

```
def create_on_task(self, task_id, file_content, file_name, file_content_type=None, **options):
        """Upload an attachment for a task. Accepts a file object or string, file name, and optional file Content-Type"""
        path = '/tasks/%d/attachments' % (task_id)
        return self.client.request('post', path, files=[('file', (file_name, file_content, file_content_type))], **options)
```

But when I am trying to pass the arguments for file and file content it shows me an error.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Another user on the Asana development forum had the same problem using the Curl API. (https://forum.asana.com/t/sending-file-with-api/16897/2). Apparently it has something to do with the 'multipart form upload'.

Looking through another thread here on stackoverflow ([How to send a "multipart/form-data" with requests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python)), it seemed the file object had to be read in binary was all.

so the parameters would be:

```
client.attachments.create_on_task(task_id=<task id here>,file_content=open(filename_with_path, 'rb'),file_name='Name_of_File',file_content_type="image/jpeg")
```