# How to fix '415 Unsupported Media Type' error in Python using requests

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests, bitbucket-server

I would like to create a commit by using bitbucket's rest api. So far, all the answers to questions about `Response 415` have been resolved by setting the `Content-Type` in the header to `application/json;charset-UTF8`. However, this does not solve the response I get.

So here is what I am trying to do:

```py
import requests

def commit_file(s, path, content, commit_message, branch, source_commit_id):
    data = dict(content=content, message=commit_message, branch=branch, sourceCommitId=source_commit_id)
    r = s.put(path, data=data, headers={'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'})
    return r.status_code

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('name', 'token')
url = 'https://example.com/api/1.0/projects/Project/repos/repo/browse/file.txt'
file = s.get(url)
r = commit_file(s, url, file.json() , 'Commit Message', 'test', '51e0f6faf64')
```

The `GET` requests successfully returns the file and I would like to commit it's contents on the branch `test` which does exist.

No matter the `Content-Type`, the `status_code` of the response is `415`.

Here is the header of the put request:

```
OrderedDict([('user-agent', ('User-Agent', 'python-requests/2.21.0')), ('accept-encoding', ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')), ('accept', ('Accept', '*/*')), ('connection', ('Connection', 'keep-alive')), ('content-type', ('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')), ('content-length', ('Content-Length', '121')), ('authorization', ('Authorization', 'Basic YnVybWF4MDA6Tnp...NkJqWGp1a2JjQ3dNZzhHeGI='))])
```

[This](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.7.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45568365784624) explains the usage with curl and when the file is locally available. How would a correct request look like in python when the content of the file are retrieved as shown above?

This is the solution by using the `MultipartEncoder`:

```
import requests
import requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder

def commit_file(s, path, content, commit_message, branch, source_commit_id):
    data = requests_toolbelt.MultipartEncoder(
        fields={
            'content': content,
            'message': commit_message,
            'branch': branch,
            'sourceCommitId': source_commit_id
        }
    )
    r = s.put(path, data=data, headers={'Content-type': data.content_type})
```

Comment: This is not a problem of the requests library. Either you are using the wrong `Content-Type`, or maybe the body of your request is wrong (just because it is JSON it does not mean that it's the correct JSON object. A request with incorrect/missing JSON fields *might* result in a 415).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content type `application/json;charset=utf-8` is incorrect.

According to the documentation, you must send multipart form data. You cannot use JSON.

> This resource accepts PUT multipart form data, containing the file in a form-field named `content`.

See: [How to send a "multipart/form-data" with requests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this does not change the status code of the response.

Comment: @Tinnitus: Ah, I read the documentation a bit more closely. Sending JSON of any kind is not correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. This resolved the issue. I have put the solution in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by adding `'Content-Type': '*/*'` and `'accept': '*/*'` in headers.