# how to post form request on python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to fill a form like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqsK3.png) and submit it automaticly. To do that, I sniffed the packets while logging in.

```
POST /?pg=ogrgiris HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://xxx.xxx.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15
Referer: http://xxx.xxx.com/?pg=ogrgiris
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
DNT: 1
Content-Length: 60
Connection: close

seviye=700&ilkodu=34&kurumkodu=317381&ogrencino=40&isim=ahm
```

I repeated that packet by burp suite and saw works porperly. the response was the html of the member page.

Now I tried to do that on python. The code is below:

```
 import requests
 url = 'http://xxx.xxx.com/?pg=ogrgiris'
 headers = {'Host':'xxx.xxx.com',
'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Referer':'http://xxx.xxx.com/?pg=ogrgiris',
'Content-Lenght':'60','Connection':'close'}

credentials = {'seviye': '700','ilkodu': '34','kurumkodu': '317381','ogrecino': '40','isim': 'ahm'}


r = requests.post(url,headers=headers, data=credentials)
print(r.content)
```

the problem is, that code prints the html of the login page even I send all of the [credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGaNi.png) enough to log in. How can I get the member page? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the POST request displays a page with the content you want, then the problem is only that you are sending data as JSON, not in "form" data format (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

If a session is created at the request base and you have to make another request for the requested data, then you have to deal with cookies.

Problem with data format:

```py
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=credentials)
```

Kwarg `json =` creates a request body as follows:

`{"ogrecino": "40", "ilkodu": "34", "isim": "ahm", "kurumkodu": "317381", "seviye": "700"}`

While `data=` creates a request body like this:

`seviye=700&ilkodu=34&kurumkodu=317381&ogrencino=40&isim=ahm`

You can try https://httpbin.org:

```py
from requests import post


msg = {"a": 1, "b": True}
print(post("https://httpbin.org/post", data=msg).json())  # Data as Form data, look at key `form`, it's object in JSON because it's Form data format
print(post("https://httpbin.org/post", json=msg).json())  # Data as json, look at key `data`, it's string
```

Comment: i updated the code as you told. but still loads the login page html :( could you please check it again?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to replicate the sample request, you are missing a lot of the headers; this in particular is very important `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because it will tell your HTTP client how to format/encode the payload.

Check the documentation for `requests` so see how these form posts can work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python/35974071

Comment: i updated the code as you told. added all of the headers in burp suite but didnt work :( could you please check it again?

Comment: Try adding an argument `files={'file': open( .. )}` and see if `requests` sends the data in the correct format. Try an empty text file or something like that.

Comment: `Content-Type` header should not be set manually in `requests`. It is being set by lib implicitly based on payload type.

Comment: so do i need headers? @Ivan Vinogradov

Comment: @user11321600 what is target URL?