# how to set Content-disposition header as attachment for file part?

Tags: python, python-requests, content-disposition

I am using the Python requests module to send a multi-part HTTP POST request that contains both form-data and a file attachment.

The "Content-disposition" header for each multi-part object is set to "form-data", including the file part.

I need the "Content-disposition" header for the form-data parts to still say "form-data", but the "Content-disposition" header for the file part must say "attachment" and not "form-data".

How do I change the content-disposition header for the file-part only?

My code:

```py
#Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 13:20:13) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]
import requests

#USER PARAMETERS
user_name = 'user_account'
password = 'user_password'
token = '45Hf4xGhj'

#REQUESTS PARAMETERS
url = '192.168.0.2'
headers = {'content-type': 'multi-part/form-data'}
data = {'Username':user_name, 'Password':password, 'Token':token}
files = {'settings': ('settings.xml', open('settings.xml', 'rb'), 'app/xml')}

#POST
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
```

This is what the file-part's header looks like with Python requests:

```html
Content-Type: app/xml
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="settings"; filename="settings.xml"
```

and this is what I need the header of the file-part to look like:

```html
Content-Type: app/xml
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="settings"; filename="settings.xml"
```

I also tried to change the header by adding a header parameter to the file:

```py
files = {'settings': ('settings.xml', open('settings.xml', 'rb'),
         'app/xml', {'Content-Disposition':'attachment'})}
```

but that had no effect. I can specify any other custom header and it will add it, but it does not change the "Content-Disposition" header if I use the approach.

Any ideas?

---

Using the toolbelt:

```
m = MultipartEncoder( fields={'Username': user_name, 
                              'Password': password, 
                              'Token': token, 
                    'settings': ('settings', open('settings.xml', 'rb'), 
                                 'app/xml', 
                                {'Content-Disposition':'attachment'}
                                )
                             } 
                    ) 

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', 
                   data=m, 
                   headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```

> results in
>
> ```
> ...--2ba9624051854b6d961bad262a1792fc 
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="settings"; filename="settings"
> Content-Type: app/xml 
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>...
> ```

Comment: Read about [requests/toolbelt](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt)

Comment: @stovfl thanks, I tried the toolbelt but no luck. It still won't change the "Content-Disposition: form-data" header to "Content-Disposition: attachment". Again, if I choose any other header name it adds that header to the file-part's header, but it won't change  "Content-Disposition".

Comment: Maybe this answer [How to send a “multipart/form-data” with requests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/7414759) can help. **Note** the second comment ***"Not setting the Content-Type header ensures that requests sets it to the correct value"***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: Set Content-disposition header as attachment for file part?

The short answer: Using `python-requests`, it's not possible, the way it is implemented now.

> **Explanation**:
>
> [requests/models.py](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/428f7a275914f60a8f1e76a7d69516d617433d30/requests/models.py)
>
> ```
> class RequestEncodingMixin(object):
>     ...
>     def _encode_files(files, data):
>         ...
>         rf = RequestField(name=k, data=fdata, filename=fn, headers=fh)
>         rf.make_multipart(content_type=ft)
> ```
>
> Variable `fh` holdes the 4th tuple item passed from
>
> ```
> files = {'settings': (filename, io.BytesIO(b'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n'),
>          'app/xml', {'Content-Disposition':'attachment'} )}
> ```
>
> The `rf.header dict` get updated passing `headers=fh` with `'Content-Disposition':...`.
>   Calling `rf.make_multipart(content_type=ft)`, at the next line, only passing the 3trd tuple item.
>
> The method [`make_multipart` - urllib3/fields.py](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/ae7f8bbb57e74ffdb327c5e510963a886fa4ed8b/src/urllib3/fields.py) is defined as
>
> ```
> def make_multipart(
>     self, content_disposition=None, content_type=None, content_location=None
> ):
>     self.headers["Content-Disposition"] = content_disposition or u"form-data"
>     ...
> ```
>
> which replaces `self.headers["Content-Disposition"]` with the default `u"form-data"`.

---

> **Possible Solutions**:

1. Use only `urllib3` there you can do

   ```
   rf.make_multipart(content_disposition=fh.get("Content-Disposition"), content_type=ft)
   ```
2. File a request to `urllib3` and/or `python-requests` to fix this issue.
3. Patch yourself, either `requests/models.py` or `urlib3/fields`.

---

> **Patch**: `def make_multipart`

Add only the default `Content-Disposition: form-data` if not already in `self.headers`.

```
from urllib3 import fields

def make_multipart(
        self, content_disposition=None, content_type=None, content_location=None
    ):
        if self.headers.get("Content-Disposition") is None:
            self.headers["Content-Disposition"] = content_disposition or u"form-data"

        self.headers["Content-Disposition"] += u"; ".join(
            [
                u"",
                self._render_parts(
                    ((u"name", self._name), (u"filename", self._filename))
                ),
            ]
        )
        self.headers["Content-Type"] = content_type
        self.headers["Content-Location"] = content_location

fields.RequestField.make_multipart = make_multipart
```

> **Resulting multipart**:
>
> ```
> --e96a4935b8d5b2355f1da3070faa4b28
> Content-Disposition: attachment; name="settings"; filename="settings.xml"
> Content-Type: app/xml
>
> some,data,to,send
> another,row,to,send
>
> --e96a4935b8d5b2355f1da3070faa4b28--
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - urllib3: 1.23 - requests: 2.19.1***

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's possible to modify the part headers after they have been generated by MultipartEncoder.

```
    for part in m.parts:
    hdr = part.headers.decode('utf-8')
    if 'settings.xml' in hdr:
        part.headers = hdr.replace('Content-Disposition: form-data;',
                  'Content-Disposition: attachment;').encode('utf-8')
```