# requests equivalent to cURL returning error

Tags: curl, post, python-requests, deepl

I am trying to use the [DeepL API](https://www.deepl.com/nl/docs-api.html?part=translating_documents). In the documentation they speak of a cURL command like so:

```sh
curl https://api.deepl.com/v2/document \
    -F "file=@mydoc.docx" \
    -F "auth_key=<your-api-key>" \
    -F "target_lang=DE"
```

which I converted to `requests` like so.

```py
import requests

files = {
    'file': ('mydoc.docx', open('mydoc.docx', 'rb')),
    'auth_key': (None, '<your-api-key>'),
    'target_lang': (None, 'DE'),
}

response = requests.post('https://api.deepl.com/v2/document', files=files)
```

Strangely enough, the cURL command does work from the command line, but I can't get the Python code to work. The server keeps returning the following data:

```py
{'message': 'Invalid file data.'}
```

The documentation explicitly states

> Because the request includes a file upload, it must be an HTTP POST request containing multipart/form-data.

But as far as I know, the above is the correct way to do this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm, since you have to open `mydoc` in read binary, do you need to send the strings as bytes instead? Like for `target_lang` use `b'DE'` instead?

Comment: @SuperStew I tried it, but no use.

Comment: I suggest you to first try converting the request in a tool like postman for example and then you can probably find all the info you need about python multipart request here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python

Comment: Have you tried opening the file for both reading and writing? It looks like the DeepL server encrypts the file after you upload it; not sure how they're doing that but it's possible they're trying to both read from and write to the file. Try `rb+` instead of `rb`.

Comment: @KaylaFuchs Tried it but no change.

Comment: Hmmm...have you tried various different files, all with the same result?

Comment: The support team got back to me and provided a solution. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DeepL support team got back to me, and the solution was to specify the data type to the file (in my case `text/plain`). So the request should look like this:

```py
import requests

files = {
    'file': ('mydoc.docx', open('mydoc.docx', 'rb'), 'text/plain'),
    'auth_key': (None, '<your-api-key>'),
    'target_lang': (None, 'DE')
}

response = requests.post('https://api.deepl.com/v2/document', files=files)
```