# Send multipart/form-data string with POST requests, python

Tags: python, python-requests, data-transfer

I want to send a string through POST request like

```
#my data string
data='[{ "DeviceNo":"123123123","LogDate":"2018-11-18", "FileName":"X.py", "LogMessage":"Message" }]'

response = requests.post(url,files=data, timeout=20, headers={'Authorization': accessToken})
```

I dont know how to send this data. Don't know if `"files=data"` is a correct usage for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a "multipart/form-data" with requests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code is the solution for me. Hope it help someone (i lost so much time on this one)

```
data={
  "request":"{ 'action':'CreateLog', 'version':'1', 'parameters': { 'Message':'my message'}}" 
     }
response = requests.post(url,data=data, timeout=20, headers={'Authorization': accessToken})
```