# Cannot send an empty message when uploading a file

Tags: python, discord

I want to send `discord.png` to a text channel using Python and the Discord API, but I keep getting an error:

> {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006"}

I think I've done everything as the Documentation said, and I don't know what's the problem.
I know, I could just use an already existing python library for this (like discord.py) but I'm only playing with the API, and I cant't figure out what is the issue here.

```
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {TOKEN}", "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}

f = open("discord.png", "rb")
file_data = f.read()
f.close()

file_data = base64.b64encode(file_data).decode()

payload_json = '{"content": "Discord", "tts": False}'
data = {
    "content": "Discord",
    "tts": False,
    "file": file_data
}

headers["User-Agent"] = "DiscordBot"
#headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data" #edited but then realised i already set the content-type
headers["Content-Disposition"] = 'form-data; name="file" filename="discord.png"'

r = requests.post(f"{http_api}/channels/{CHANNEL_ID}/messages", data, headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple tiny mistakes in your code, but the main issue here is actually that the Discord documentation is very misleading.

When sending a file (or multiple files) this is *not* done by sending the contents in the `file` field of the request as the documentation indicates. Rather, the file(s) should be in the body of the request, as in the second example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition):

```
POST /test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="boundary"

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"

value1
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"; filename="example.txt"

value2
--boundary--
```

The `requests` module allows us to do this very conveniently with the `files` parameter:

```py
data = {"payload_json": payload_json}
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {TOKEN}", "User-Agent": "DiscordBot"}
r = requests.post(f"{http_api}/channels/{CHANNEL_ID}/messages", data,
                  files={"discord.png": file_data}, headers=headers)
```

And note there is no need to set the `Content-Type` or `Content-Disposition` headers – `requests` will take care of that for you.

For more examples/explanation of making requests with the `files` parameter, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12385179/5495792).