# How to make form data request in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

How Can I create below multi-part form data request by uploading file in Python?

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryKVAJlF8rFOTxL7jq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="txtresume.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
------WebKitFormBoundaryKVAJlF8rFOTxL7jq--
```

also how can i post this request in python

Comment: Your answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use requests module to post file

```
import reqeusts
url = 'http://yoururl/'
files = {'file': open('xxx.xls', 'rb')} # or files = {'file': ('xxx.xls', open('xxx.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
r = reqeusts.post(url, files=files)
```

For more resource you can view this [link](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)