# Send POST multipart python

Tags: python, python-requests

try post to API with python :

```
import requests
import json

url='https://link.html'

data = {
'keyfile':{
'valuekey1': 'data1',
'valuekey2': 'data2'
}
}

payload = {'keypost': data}

headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>',
#'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response)
print(response.text)
```

in API catch multipart form data with key "keypost" then get json with "keyfile" but the "keypost" and "keyfile" can't catch on API, what i'm wrong when send post data in python requests ?

[UPDATE]
try to change payload with this and successfull:

```
payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"keypost\"\r\n\r\n{\"keyfile\": {\"valuekey1\": \"data1\", \"valuekey2\":\"data2\"}}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
```

whats diferent payload 1 and payload 2:

1. ```
   data = {
   'keyfile':{
   'valuekey1': 'data1',
   'valuekey2': 'data2'
   }
   }

   payload = {'keypost': data}
   ```
2. ```
   ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"keypost\"\r\n\r\n{\"keyfile\": {\"valuekey1\": \"data1\", \"valuekey2\":\"data2\"}}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
   ```

but i want still payload 1 because look simple ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If yes, please include the stacktrace in the post.

Comment: on python request, nothing errors, but on API cant catch the key

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python

Comment: the answer should use another library

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
data = {
    'valuekey1': 'data1',
    'valuekey2': 'data2'
}

payload = {'keypost': data}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.