# Python - API POST with Form-Data file upload

Tags: python

[POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xNEX.png)  i have tried everything to duplicate a POSTMAN POST that is working using Python and i have been unsuccessful.  I receive a 500 back and when i print the request I dont see anything wrong.  Any suggestions?

````
```
filename1="untitled.png"
filename="untitled.png"
location = "C:\\myfiles\\"


#files = {"file":(filename1,open(location+'/'+filename,"rb"),'application-type')}
#files = {"file":(filename1,open(location+'/'+filename,"rb"))}
#files = {"file":(filename1, open(location+'/'+filename,'rb'),'application-type')}
files = {'file': (filename1, open(location+'/'+filename,'rb'))}


payload = {'': {
    "DateIssued": "2020-02-22T14:35:40.760026-08:00",
    "Category":None,
    "Title":"Report",
    "Title2":"MyReports"
}}

headers = {
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'PublishService-Api-Key': 'myAPIKey'

}

req = requests.request('POST',"http://myurl.com/PublishService/api/docs/", headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
print(req)

```
````

Comment: Put the payload on a single line and the headers on a single line (no line breaks) and try again. I've had this problem before.

Comment: can you share postman request screenshot?

Comment: i added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `Content-Type` from header.

```
headers = {
  'PublishService-Api-Key': 'myAPIKey'
}
```

Explanation here --> [How to send a "multipart/form-data" with requests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python)

[image: 1]

Comment: After removing Content Type it i still receive a 500 response

Comment: try this, with modified header . `req = requests.post("http://myurl.com/PublishService/api/docs/", headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)`

Comment: can you also check the error message, status code is 500 but because of what?

Comment: your postman snip shows, you are passing the image under `myfile` variable whereas your python code has `file` key.  
`files = {'file': (filename1, open(location+'/'+filename,'rb'))}`  Change it to myfile

Comment: Thank you for the response. Our API uses the key as the name of the file in the system.  i can change that to anything and it will give me a 200 in POSTMAN and be received correctly.  Just as long as a valid file is attached.  If it is not i receive a 500.  i am not sure how to check the errors.  i just see.{"Message":"An error has occurred."}