# Can't correctly transfer curl/fetch to python

Tags: javascript, python, nginx, curl, fetch

I'm currently writing simple message-sending app.
It should just send a message in a txt file to the server.

Fetch request looks like this:

```
fetch(url, 
{"credentials":"include",
"headers":{"accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01","accept-language":"ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7","content-type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW","is-api-query":"true","x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest"},
"referrer":"",
"referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade",
"body":"------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oid\"\r\n\r\n560579\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uid\"\r\n\r\n20591\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n2\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"coion\"\r\n\r\n259\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"rec\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[]\"; filename=\"sample.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"chht\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"csctoe\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cuid\"\r\n\r\n133338\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cclid\"\r\n\r\n2155\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cwid\"\r\n\r\n0\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"coid\"\r\n\r\n589454\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW--\r\n",
"method":"POST",
"mode":"cors"});
```

It works fine and it sends an empty file with the name "sample.txt". But when I'm trying to do the same in Python, server returns that the request's body is incorrect.

I've tried sending it as it is:

```
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'is-api-query': 'true',
    'DNT': '1',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW',
    'Origin': '',
    'Referer': '',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

data = '^------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^text^\\^^\n\n^\n\n^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^oid^\\^^\n\n^\n\n560579^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^uid^\\^^\n\n^\n\n20591^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^type^\\^^\n\n^\n\n2^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^coion^\\^^\n\n^\n\n259^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^recipient^\\^^\n\n^\n\n1^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^upload^[^]^\\^; filename=^\\^sample.txt^\\^^\n\nContent-Type: text/plain^\n\n^\n\n^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^chht^\\^^\n\n^\n\n^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^csctoe^\\^^\n\n^\n\n1^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^cuid^\\^^\n\n^\n\n133338^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^cclid^\\^^\n\n^\n\n2155^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^cwid^\\^^\n\n^\n\n0^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW^\n\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=^\\^coid^\\^^\n\n^\n\n589454^\n\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMdUdjyDYgjOTGBXW--^\n\n^'

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

I also tried sending data as json.dumps(), but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The minimal JSON that is valid is `{}`

Comment: The `requests()` module can format the POST data for you, I suggest you do that instead of trying to format it yourself.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/5274713 sending raw form-data could be a bit harder.