# Upload file to Django using requests.post()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm quite new to django and I just can't figure out a way to upload a simple html file to django using requests.post(). I tried the steps given in this https://blog.vivekshukla.xyz/uploading-file-using-api-django-rest-framework/  but I keep getting a status 400 when I give

```
import requests
file_ob = open("/root/Desktop/sampletext.html", "rb")
print(file_ob)
payload = {
    'remark1': 'hey',
    'remark2': 'hello',
    'File': file_ob
}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/files/", data=payload)
print(r.status_code)
```

models.py

```
class Files(models.Model):
    remark1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    remark2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    File = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
```

views.py

```
class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self, request):
        files = Files.objects.all()
        file_serializer = FileSerializer(files, many=True)
        return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializers.py

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Files
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('upload/files/', FileView.as_view())
]
```

Here is the error I get from server:

```
Bad Request: /upload/files/
[12/May/2020 08:29:45] "POST /upload/files/ HTTP/1.1" 400 84
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this? I cant find any example online where `requests.post()` was used. It's Postman everywhere.

Comment: please add the output of `file_serializer.errors`.

Comment: general tip: avoid using variables starting with capital letters. Those are intended for class definitions. Instead of `File` you should stick to `file`.

Comment: Also, files need to be sent separately as mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/1320407

Update your `requests.post` as per the examples, and try again.

Comment: Tip noted. Just started to program 3 months ago, so not so well versed with the conventions. Yep passing the files separately did the trick. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
import requests
file_ob = {'uploaded_file': open('/root/Desktop/sampletext.html', 'rb')
print(file_ob)
payload = {
    'remark1': 'hey',
    'remark2': 'hello',
}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/files/", files=file_ob, data=payload)

print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the "accept" button.