# How can I post payload with requests in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

This is what I observed with f12 in chrome:
[image: chrome output]

The payload here doesn't seem like json data since there is 89:42 in the front.

```
payload = ["auth",{"form":{"id":"xxxx","email":"xxx@xxx"}}]
resp = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
print(resp.status_code)

payload = '89:42["auth",{"form":{"id":"xxxx","email":"xxx@xxx"}}]'
resp = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(resp.status_code)
```

The status code of the above resp are both 400(bad request). How can I post it correctly?

[EDIT] I actually used `Session` to maintain the session. I'v also tried to change the content-type to `application/json`. But it didn't work. And as your can see in the picture, the default content-type seen with f12 is `text/plain`.

[EDIT] Some said the `data` or `json` argument must be a `dict`. Does it means that I should rewrite `89:42["auth",{"form":{"id":"xxxx","email":"xxx@xxx"}}]` to change its type to `dict`? How should I do this?

Comment: There's a session as well. The authentication might be related to the session.

Comment: The `json` or `data` argument should be a `dict`.

Comment: content-type might matter, as well as session cookies.  note that you can dump out the `resp.request` to see what `requests` is sending, can be useful to see how it compares

Comment: The format of the payload seems like the serialization in `PHP`.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request), you need to pass your payload as a dictoinary like this:

```py
response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

Comment: I don't think it would success by passing them like this.The format of post is not `form-data`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA if you want to send `multipart/form-data` encoded data, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/11804213

Comment: The Request Payload is `89:42["auth",{"form":{"id":"xxxx","email":"xxx@xxx"}}]`. How can I change it into a `dict`？