# Read csv from s3 and upload to external api as multipart

Tags: api, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, multipartform-data

I want to read the csv file from the s3 bucket using boto3 and upload it to external API using multipart/form-data request.
so far I am able to read the csv

```
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
body = response['Body']
```

Not sure on how to convert this body into multipart.
External api will be taking request in multipart/form-data.
Any Suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Can you add more details? What's the specification of the external API?

Comment: @jellycsc external api will be taking request in multipart/form-data

Comment: @jellycsc i have updated my question.

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with AWS or S3. What you need is to make a request with `multipart/form-data`, check out whether this answer helps or not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/2361752

Comment: @xhg i want to convert my response which is taken from boto3 to multipart. I have checked the link, but I haven't got any solution.

Comment: you can start by: 1. understand what a multipart request needs, is it a stream or other data type; 2. understand what data type boto3 produced; 3. if the types match, great, if not, you need to do conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following method solved my issue.

```
body = response['Body'].read()
multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
        fields={
            'file': (file_name, body, 'application/vnd.ms-excel'),
            'field01': 'test'
        }
    )
```

.read() method will convert the file into binary string.