# Python web scraping: How to configure multipart/form-data payload

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm trying to scrape this site:
https://kfz.virtuelles-rathaus.de/igv2-man/servlet/Internetgeschaeftsvorfaelle

But I can't figure out how to set up a valid request body.
The Status Code is 200, so the request itself works.
In the response it says it couldn't process to data, because I used the Browser navigation. It wants me to use the Website buttons instead.

I think it is because the payload isn't configured correctly, but I can't get it to work.

I already tried following:

- Setting the headers manually
- Using requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder
- Creating the boundary for the multipart/data-format myself

The **decodedPayload** copied from Chrome Dev Tools

> WKZ_UNTERSCH_Z: WT
> WKZ_ERKENN_Z: SJ
> WKZ_ZIFFERN: 454
> WKZ_SUCHMERKMAL: NULL
> BTN_WKZSUCHE: suchen
> ZEITSTEMPEL: 2022040815031191

The **encoded Payload** copied from Chrome Dev Tools

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryj9dFOsSgrDr5dSwA
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="WKZ_UNTERSCH_Z"
>
> WT
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryj9dFOsSgrDr5dSwA
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="WKZ_ERKENN_Z"
>
> SJ
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryj9dFOsSgrDr5dSwA
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="WKZ_ZIFFERN"
>
> 454
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryj9dFOsSgrDr5dSwA
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="WKZ_SUCHMERKMAL"
>
> NULL
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryj9dFOsSgrDr5dSwA
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BTN_WKZSUCHE"
>
> suchen
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryj9dFOsSgrDr5dSwA
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ZEITSTEMPEL"
>
> 2022040815031191
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryj9dFOsSgrDr5dSwA--

**My Code:**

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime


def main():

    payload = {"WKZ_UNTERSCH_Z": "WT",
               "WKZ_ERKENN_Z": "GH",
               "WKZ_ZIFFERN": "454",
               "WKZ_SUCHMERKMAL": "NULL",
               "BTN_WKZSUCHE": "suchen",
               "ZEITSTEMPEL": datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d%H%S%M%f')[:-4]}

    url = 'https://kfz.virtuelles-rathaus.de/igv2-man/servlet/Internetgeschaeftsvorfaelle'

    # Initialize Session and get Cookie with session ID
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(f'{url}?MANDANT=08337000&AUFRUF=WKZ')

    r = s.post(
        f'{url}', data=payload, verify=False)

    # Save Response for further scraping
    with open('z_1.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(r.text))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**I already thank you guys in advance for your help**

**EDIT:**

The Body that's created when using the MultipartEncoder:

> --b3dccffd58a47883c42249db16600856
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="WKZ_UNTERSCH_Z"
>
> WT
> --b3dccffd58a47883c42249db16600856
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="WKZ_ERKENN_Z"
>
> SJ
> --b3dccffd58a47883c42249db16600856
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="WKZ_ZIFFERN"
>
> 454
> --b3dccffd58a47883c42249db16600856
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="WKZ_SUCHMERKMAL"
>
> NULL
> --b3dccffd58a47883c42249db16600856
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BTN_WKZSUCHE"
>
> suchen
> --b3dccffd58a47883c42249db16600856
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ZEITSTEMPEL"
>
> 2022040909485493
> --b3dccffd58a47883c42249db16600856--

Comment: Check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python

Comment: @Hans thank you. It helped me to understand it a bit better, but I still couldn't figure it out.
I finally undrstood, that that Boundary doens't need the same format. But the server doens't accept my data.
I don't get an error. The server tells me not to use the Browser navigation button, I should use the Buttons provided by the Website.

I had the same Problem with another site, there I had to update Session Ids in the payload. This time its another problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem

I wasn't a problem with the data format, but I used the wrong timestamp.

The solution is to use the timestamp of the previous response and not the current time.