# How to add both file and JSON Form in a FastAPI POST request?

Tags: python, http, http-post, fastapi, pydantic

Specifically, I want the below example to work:

**app.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI,File,UploadFile,Form,Body
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.get("/hello/{name}")
async def say_hello(name: str):
    return {"message": f"Hello {name}"}

@app.post("/jsk")
async def save_image_meta(farm_name: str = Form(...), files: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print('*'*100)
    return {
        "farm_name": farm_name
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8088, reload=True)
```

If this is not a proper way for a POST request, please advise me how to select required columns from an uploaded image file in FastAPI.

**test.py**

```
import base64
import hmac
import json
import requests

def parse_params_to_str(params):
    url = "?"
    for key, value in params.items():
        url = url + str(key) + '=' + str(value) + '&'
    return url[1:-1]

def hash_string(qs, secret_key):
    mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'), bytes(qs, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
    d = mac.digest()
    validating_secret = str(base64.b64encode(d).decode('utf-8'))
    return validating_secret

def sample_request():
    access_key = "dfaa65a6-ee25-4b03-916b-bedb9095-35f9-4485-a72e-5da4e161a12b"
    secret_key = "GWpnn56bUOnCedhpiUWYJl9dtZ3WllWtUeBUGQva"
    qs = dict(key=access_key)
    header_secret = hash_string(parse_params_to_str(qs), secret_key)
    url = f"http://127.0.0.1:8088/jsk"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'secret': header_secret
    }
    file = "/Users/jskim/Downloads/111111.jpg"
    files = {'files': open(file, 'rb')}
    payload = {"farm_name": "11111"}
    res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, files=files)
    return res

sample_request()
```

I am getting a `400 Bad Request` error.

If this is not a proper way for a POST request, please advise me how to select required columns from an uploaded image file in FastAPI.

Comment: Additioanlly, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804) with regards to setting the `Content-Type` header in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not define the `Content-Type multipart/form-data` header yourself. The `requests` library takes care of this automatically by defining the boundary. If you set this header yourself, `requests` will not do it and your server will not know what boundary to expect (unless you decide to also set the boundary yourself).

To work your header should be without the content-type:

```py
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        secret: header_secret
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i'll give you what i did in mine project , i hope it'll help you

its basic but helpful

> my schema

```
class UserProfileSchema(BaseModel):
       first_name: str 
       last_name: str 
       address: Optional[Text]
       image: Optional[str]
       postal_code: Optional[str]
       national_code: Optional[int]

      @classmethod
      def as_form(cls, first_name: str = Form(...), last_name: str = Form(...), address: Optional[Text] = Form(...),
            postal_code: Optional[str] = Form(...),
            national_code: Optional[str] = Form(...)):
           return cls(first_name=first_name,
               last_name=last_name,
               address=address,
               postal_code=postal_code,
               national_code=national_code)
     class Config:
           orm_mode = True
```

> my view

```
    @wrapper_auth('/profile')
    class Profile:
        async def post(profile: UserProfileSchema = Depends(UserProfileSchema.as_form), file: UploadFile = File(...),
                       current_user: User = Security(get_current_user), db: get_session = Depends(get_db)) -> jsonable_encoder:
.......
```