# Structure of HTML Form Data

Tags: python, header-files, mechanize

I know this is stupid question but how does payload of this form data be formatted. I can't make request more than one time so i can't see real request send.

I have tried same on local html file and then tries to make request but i don't know if image attachment will be right or not.

```
<form method="post" id="txnForm" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" action="https://example.com"> 

<div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Name : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Address : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Occupation : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="occupation[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Mobile : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Email : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Aadhar No: </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="aadhar_no[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Aadhar Image: </label><br>
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="aadhar_image" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                          

                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Name : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Address : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Occupation : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="occupation[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Mobile : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Email : </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Aadhar No: </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="aadhar_no[]" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Aadhar Image: </label><br>
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="aadhar_image" required="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</form>
```

If I'm right then form data will look like this:

```
        formData = {
            'aadhar_no[]' : ['123456789', '123456789', '123456789', '123456789'],
            'address[]' : [],
            'csrf_token' : csrf_token,
            'email[]' : [],
            'member_id' : member_id,
            'mobile[]' : [],
            'name[]' : [],
            'occupation[]' : [],
            'aadhar_image' : []
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML form data is never sent via Javascript.  The two primary types are `multipart/form-data`, which is required when you have a file field, and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is the default, and is much more compact.  `multipart/form-data` is sent like a MIME-encoded email:

Your data will be sent like this.  The spec is in RFC 7578: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data, boundary=---1234

---1234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name[]"

value-of-name-field
---1234 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address[]"

value-of-address-field
---1234 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="occupation[]"

value-of-occupation-field
---1234 
......
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="aadhar_image[]"
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=---5678

--5678
Content-Disposition: file; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

.... jpeg image data ...
--5678
--1234
```

Many of the web frameworks will convert this to JSON for you, but that's not how it crosses the wire.

Comment: So it does mean multipart/form-data could not send manually python?

Comment: Ah, now I see that I misunderstood your question.  You were asking how to SIMULATE that request from Python code.  It depends on what library you use.  The `requests` module will send multipart/form-data automatically if you include a "files" parameter.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python

Comment: ohh Thanks! Wish me luck :)