# Why shows this error when adding the file "Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable"?

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework

My target is to build a form that besides `charfields` will have a `file field` and all data of the fields will be stored in the database. The form does store the `charfield`'s data, but after adding a new field as `filefield` It not working when I submit, and shows the below error. Why is not store the `filefield`'s data?

***views.py:***

```
def employeeListView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return redirect("/")

def InsertAndInfo(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        file = request.FILES['filedf'] #if 'filedf' in request.FILES else None

        data = {
            'name':name,     
            'email':email,
            'phone':phone,
            'file':file
        }

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees/',json=data,headers=headers)
        return redirect("/api/")


    employeeInfoApiLink = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/AllElmployeeInfo/').json()
    context = {
        "employeeInfo":employeeInfoApiLink
    }
    return render(request, 'InsertAndInfo.html',context)
```

***models.py:***

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="file/",null=True)
```

***serializer.py:***

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = "__all__"
```

***form.html:***

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone">
    <input type="file" name="filedf" class="form-control" id="file">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

***Errors:***

```
TypeError at /api/
Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable
Exception Location: C:\Users\DCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py, line 179, in default
Python Executable:  C:\Users\DCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\7_ProgrammingLanguage\\1_FrameWork\\4_Django-Rest-Frame-work\\2.1_CBVproject',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 30 Oct 2022 18:29:17 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send `File` as JSON object. JSON does not support this feature. You should use `form data`.  You can check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/7437136)

```py
        data = {
            'name':name,     
            'email':email,
            'phone':phone,
        }
        files = [("files", file)]

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

        requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees/',data=data,headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: I have read the answer you have given. But I didn't catch that. Could you please write the solution?

Comment: I added code sample

Comment: not working....