# Whatsapp cloud API uploading media get error file type using python

Tags: python, post, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, whatsapp

So i'm trying to upload an image to facebook graph API whatsapp media (having a hard time with how they name things) i tried on postman first and successfully get the uploaded media ID, but when i tried this on python with `request` objects i got error response 400 something like this:

> ... Param file must be a file with one of the following types: ...

This is what i tried

```
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{phone_id}/media"
head = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}
files = {
    'file': open(current+'\default.png', 'rb'),
}

upload_media = requests.post(
    url, 
    data={
        'messaging_product' : 'whatsapp', 
        'type': 'image/png',
    },
    files=files,
    headers=head
)
```

`current` here is the local path to my file and i checked out there is nothing wrong with the file (i got the binary version of the file, when printing request), i read on other answer in stackoverflow and they said i should not put `Content-Type` in the headers and let the `request` object handles this so i follow.

Here is the response i got after printing out `upload_media` and `upload_media.text`:

> <Response [400]>

> {
> "error":{
> "message":"(#100) Param file must be a file with one of the following types: audio/aac, audio/mp4, audio/mpeg, audio/amr, audio/ogg, audio/opus, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/pdf, text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, image/jpeg,  image/png, image/webp, video/mp4, video/3gpp. Received file of type ''.",
> "type":"OAuthException",
> "code":100,
> "fbtrace_id":"let me hide this seems sensitive"
> }
> }

i did make sure the file type is image .png (i also tried .jpeg, .pdf same result i think it is the header or maybe the way python `request` send the file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problems quoting answer from
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python)

answer by runejuhl

> Requests has changed since some of the previous answers were written. Have a look at this Issue on Github for more details and this comment for an example.

so i changed this

```
files = {
    'file': open(current+'/default.png', 'rb'),
}
```

into this

```
files = {
    'file': ('default.png', open(current+'/default.png', 'rb'), 'image/png', {'Expires': '0'}),
}
```

It seems the new `request` object required the format as tupple with the file type like `image/png`