# Speechmatics submit a job without audio argument

Tags: python, django

I have implemented a SpeechMatics speech to text application with their API as given in this document  [with the code](https://docs.speechmatics.com/introduction/batch-guide) below :

```
from speechmatics.models import ConnectionSettings
from speechmatics.batch_client import BatchClient
from httpx import HTTPStatusError 

API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"
PATH_TO_FILE = "example.wav"
LANGUAGE = "en"

settings = ConnectionSettings(
    url="https://asr.api.speechmatics.com/v2",
    auth_token=API_KEY,
)

# Define transcription parameters
conf = {
    "type": "transcription",
    "transcription_config": { 
        "language": LANGUAGE 
    }
}

# Open the client using a context manager
with BatchClient(settings) as client:
    try:
        job_id = client.submit_job(
            audio=PATH_TO_FILE,
            transcription_config=conf,
        )
        print(f'job {job_id} submitted successfully, waiting for transcript')

        # Note that in production, you should set up notifications instead of polling. 
        # Notifications are described here: https://docs.speechmatics.com/features-other/notifications
        transcript = client.wait_for_completion(job_id, transcription_format='txt')
        # To see the full output, try setting transcription_format='json-v2'.
        print(transcript)
    except HTTPStatusError:
        print('Invalid API key - Check your API_KEY at the top of the code!')
```

The code uses a file as an argument for the submit_job function. I want to submit a job, with fetch_data that uses a URL instead of a local file.

However, the submit_job function requires an audio argument.

I just want to use fetch_data option as given [here](https://docs.speechmatics.com/features-other/fetch-url) and no audio argument as given below :

```
conf = {
  "type": "transcription",
  "transcription_config": {
    "language": "en",
    "diarization": "speaker"
  },
  "fetch_data": {
    "url": "${URL}/{FILENAME}"
  }
}
```

How can I use fetch_data configuration that is given above and able to use submit_job function without an audio file as an argument ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunaly, I don't think the speechmatics python client currently supports using the fetch_data feature. I'm a senior software engineer at Speechmatics, and this is a known problem that we're looking into.

It is possible to send the fetch_data to the server with an empty audio file, but it gets rejected with a 400 error as it can't accept both inputs at once, so for now there is no solution that uses the SDK.

However, the SDK is really just a thin wrapper around the RESTful API. It is possible to write a simple python script that uses the requests module to achieve the same thing. I wrote the below script and tested it against a wikimedia audio file and it worked okay.

It just sends a basic http post request, then uses the job_id to poll for the job status until the status is finished running. Then it gets the transcript (which will default to json format) and prints it out (as a raw string, not json - but can be converted to json with json.loads()). Here's the code:

```python
import requests
import json
import time

API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"
LANGUAGE = "en"
AUDIO_URL = "YOUR_URL"

conf = {
    "type": "transcription",
    "transcription_config": {"language": LANGUAGE, "diarization": "speaker"},
    "fetch_data": {"url": AUDIO_URL},
}

response = requests.post(
    "https://asr.api.speechmatics.com/v2/jobs",
    data={"config": json.dumps(conf).encode()},
    files=dict(config=None),
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {API_KEY}"},
)

print(response.content)
job_id = json.loads(response.content)["id"]

job = requests.get(
    f"https://asr.api.speechmatics.com/v2/jobs/{job_id}",
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {API_KEY}"},
)
status = json.loads(job.content)["job"]["status"]

while status == "running":
    time.sleep(10)
    job = requests.get(
        f"https://asr.api.speechmatics.com/v2/jobs/{job_id}",
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {API_KEY}"},
    )
    status = json.loads(job.content)["job"]["status"]
    print(status)

transcript = requests.get(
    f"https://asr.api.speechmatics.com/v2/jobs/{job_id}/transcript",
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {API_KEY}"},
)
print(transcript.content)
```

I sent an empty "files" dict to force the request into a multipart/form-data mime type (in case you were wondering why that was there, the server only accepts multipart/form-data). You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python)

Hopefully, the SDK will get fixed soon, but for now this is the best type of approach available. Hope that helps!

P.S. there is already an open issue in [github](https://github.com/speechmatics/speechmatics-python/issues/54) about this from February, but we've not had time to get round to it yet :(

**UPDATE - 19 June 23**

We finally got round to fixing and releasing this bug - huzzah! You should now be able to use fetch data with the python client as in the example you have given above, you just need to set `audio=None`. Here's an example using a wikimedia file:

```
from speechmatics.models import ConnectionSettings
from speechmatics.batch_client import BatchClient
from httpx import HTTPStatusError 

# Define transcription parameters
conf = {
  "type": "transcription",
  "transcription_config": {
    "language": "en",
    "diarization": "speaker"
  },
  "fetch_data": {
    "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/%28eng%29-%28US%29-Man-of-war.wav"
  }
}

# Open the client using a context manager
with BatchClient() as client:
    try:
        job_id = client.submit_job(
            audio=None,
            transcription_config=conf,
        )
        print(f'job {job_id} submitted successfully, waiting for transcript')
        transcript = client.wait_for_completion(job_id, transcription_format='txt')
        print(transcript)
    except HTTPStatusError:
        print('Invalid API key - Check your API_KEY at the top of the code!')
```

It's worth noting that this example also makes use of a few other recent changes, which is why it has fewer configuration steps than the previous ones. The python client will now read auth and url config from a local toml file which can be set using the CLI command like `speechmatics config set --{arg_name} {arg_value}`. Config can also still be provided in the previous manner as well.